# Playing sound notifications using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

How can I do that, so whenever a user clicks a link we play a sound? Using javascript and jquery here.

Comment: I've wrote a jQ plugin for audio control http://soundplay.nikolavukovic.net63.net, it supports what you asking and more, docs are bundled with JavaScript code, check it out.

Comment: You can ( for example ) populate playlist(s) with a bunch of page sound effects and `.load()`, `.play()` them in key moments using the api.

Comment: For the love of all things holy, include a mute option. Links with sounds is one of the quickest ways to ensure a user never comes back to your site.

Answer (score 49):

Use this plugin: https://github.com/admsev/jquery-play-sound

```js
$.playSound('http://example.org/sound.mp3');
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it so it pulls the url of the actual link?

Comment: @hakarune: Yes, just remove the ".mp3" ending from the [source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/admsev/jquery-play-sound/master/jquery.playSound.js).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38571639/2218697)  plays sounds if **browser is inactive or minimized** by the user.  Hope helps someone.

Answer (score 26):

Put an `<audio>` element on your page.
Get your audio element and call the `play()` method:

```
document.getElementById('yourAudioTag').play();
```

Check out this example: http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/audio.html

[This site](http://blog.gingertech.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/LCA_MM_AVProc2011/#slide6) uncovers some of the other cool things you can do such as `load()`, `pause()`, and a few other properties of the audio element.

When exactly you want to play this audio element is up to you. Read the text of the button and compare it to "no" if you like.

### Alternatively

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

SoundManager 2 provides a easy to use API that allows sound to be played in any modern browser, including IE 6+. If the browser doesn't support HTML5, then it gets help from flash. If you want stricly HTML5 and no flash, there's a setting for that, preferFlash=false

It supports 100% Flash-free audio on iPad, iPhone (iOS4) and other HTML5-enabled devices + browsers

Use is as simple as:

```
<script src="soundmanager2.js"></script>
<script>
// where to find flash SWFs, if needed...
soundManager.url = '/path/to/swf-files/';

soundManager.onready(function() {
    soundManager.createSound({
        id: 'mySound',
        url: '/path/to/an.mp3'
    });

    // ...and play it
    soundManager.play('mySound');
});
```

Here's a demo of it in action: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/christmas-lights/

Answer (score 21):

Found something like that:

```
//javascript:
function playSound( url ){   
  document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML="<embed src='"+url+"' hidden=true autostart=true loop=false>";
}
```

Comment: This is to slow. It take nearly a second to play with windows browsers

Comment: @Codeglot that depends on the application.  1 Second would meet my requirements.

Comment: Also, you could probably preload it somehow to get rid of the delay.

Comment: The delay comes from the DOM parsing, then loading the file, and starting it. If you preload it, then you can just [start it when needed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2779515/99923).

Comment: 1 second after a mousedown event is a long time. Too long.

Answer (score 13):

Using the html5 audio tag and jquery:

```
// appending HTML5 Audio Tag in HTML Body
$('<audio id="chatAudio">
    <source src="notify.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="notify.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>').appendTo('body');

// play sound
$('#chatAudio')[0].play();
```

Code [from here](http://www.9lessons.info/2013/04/play-notification-sound-using-jquery.html).

In my implementation I added the audio embed directly into the HTML without jquery append.

Comment: Just for reference, I am playing sound on success handler from ajax function (which runs on page load) , and get this error:  `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first`, Chrome `Version 70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)`...seems to be solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52821721

Answer (score 9):

JavaScript Sound Manager:

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Answer (score 7):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('embed').remove();
    $('body').append('<embed src="/path/to/your/sound.wav" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">');
});
```

Comment: Why does doing this method make the scroll bars blue in Chrome?

Comment: Open this link it will solve both problem the scrol bar and also play sound http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483455/play-sound-when-message-received

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a small function that can do it, with the Web Audio API...

```
var beep = function(duration, type, finishedCallback) {

    if (!(window.audioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)) {
        throw Error("Your browser does not support Audio Context.");
    }

    duration = +duration;

    // Only 0-4 are valid types.
    type = (type % 5) || 0;

    if (typeof finishedCallback != "function") {
        finishedCallback = function() {};   
    }

    var ctx = new (window.audioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
    var osc = ctx.createOscillator();

    osc.type = type;

    osc.connect(ctx.destination);
    osc.noteOn(0);

    setTimeout(function() {
        osc.noteOff(0);
        finishedCallback();
    }, duration);

};
```

Answer (score 2):

New emerger... seems to be compatible with IE, Gecko browsers and iPhone so far...

http://www.jplayer.org/

Answer (score 2):

Following code might help you to play sound in a web page using javascript only. You can see further details at http://sourcecodemania.com/playing-sound-javascript-flash-player/

```
<script>
function getPlayer(pid) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(pid);
    if (obj.doPlay) return obj;
    for(i=0; i<obj.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = obj.childNodes[i];
        if (child.tagName == "EMBED") return child;
    }
}
function doPlay(fname) {
    var player=getPlayer("audio1");
    player.play(fname);
}
function doStop() {
    var player=getPlayer("audio1");
    player.doStop();
}
</script>

<form>
<input type="button" value="Play Sound" onClick="doPlay('texi.wav')">
<a href="#" onClick="doPlay('texi.wav')">[Play]</a>
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
    width="40"
    height="40"
    id="audio1"
    align="middle">
    <embed src="wavplayer.swf?h=20&w=20"
        bgcolor="#ffffff"
        width="40"
        height="40"
        allowScriptAccess="always"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
    />
</object>

<input type="button" value="Stop Sound" onClick="doStop()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, i'd not like that as a user.

The best way to do is probably using a small flash applet that plays your sound in the background.

Also answered here: [Cross-platform, cross-browser way to play sound from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript)

Comment: What's so bad about it if the user knows a sound would be played?

Comment: It is useful, what about if a user need an beep alert, when new orders arrive? perhaps users are not with eyes on screen the whole time, perhaps I need a pee and turn on the BEEP, then someone else can answer the order.. just few examples..