# How do I make JavaScript beep?

Tags: javascript, audio, browser, beep

I want my web page to beep whenever a user exceeds the maximum character limit of my `<textarea>`.

Comment: [Sort of a Dupe..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450033/playing-sound-notifications-using-javascript)

Comment: Why not use <blink> with a warning message instead?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript

Comment: What if the person is keying from another page and not looking at the screen? They'll never see the visual cue, and keep typing. They need a beep to stop.

Comment: For those wondering why you would do this ... in corporate environments it is common for a user to be keying blind (i.e. without looking at the screen).  Non-obtrusive audio cues can help facilitate fast keyboard-only data entry.

Comment: Lots of medium-level (or inferior senior-level) developers here are over-generalizing. Yes, it's usually bad form to play audio. However, there are definitely some perfectly good production use cases for it. If somebody hasn't written enough apps to appreciate the need, they should say that they haven't come across a valid need, not instruct others that it is never appropriate for production apps just because they haven't come across the need in their vast, yet hereby proven-inadequate, experience.

Comment: Don't listen to all these chads, I need this to create myself a little beeping metronome for a music drill. When people start to question your question because they can't imagine a context, that's yer sign.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

It's not possible to do directly in JavaScript. You'll need to embed a short WAV file in the HTML, and then play that via code.

An Example:

```html
<script>
function PlaySound(soundObj) {
  var sound = document.getElementById(soundObj);
  sound.Play();
}
</script>

<embed src="success.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="sound1"
enablejavascript="true">
```

You would then call it from JavaScript code as such:

```
PlaySound("sound1");
```

This should do exactly what you want - you'll just need to find/create the beep sound yourself, which should be trivial.

Comment: Note: Although I've given the direct answer, I do believe Mark Hurd is offering sound advice regarding not annoying the user.

Comment: You may also experience browser compatibility issues with this style of playing sound. PLaying sound from a browser in a cross-browser compatible way is hard!

Comment: Isn't it possible to have access to the PC Speaker? (from which we hear BIOS beeps)

Comment: @Nirmal, no and FYI modern PC cases don't even have "buzzers" anymore (at least in the 3 last cases I bought).

Comment: Hi @Noldorin, can you tell me the browser compatibility of your code? Specifically, the lowest versions of FF,Chrome,IE,Safari and Opera that will let the sound play?

Comment: Cupidvogel see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769077/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-using-jquery-1-4

Comment: I get `TypeError: sound.Play is not a function` (in Firefox).

Comment: This accepted answer is out of date. In order for it to work, you have to change the embed to a modern day HTML5 audio element or you will get "sound.Play is not a function"

Comment: It's better to use the `<audio />` tag I think

Answer (score 627):

**Solution**

You can now use [base64 files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to produce sounds when imported as [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). The solution is almost the same as the previous ones, except you do not need to import an external audio file.

```
function beep() {
    var snd = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64,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");  
    snd.play();
}
beep();
```

**Compatibility**

Data URI is supported on almost every browser now. More information on http://caniuse.com/datauri

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/7EAgz/

**Conversion Tool**

And here is where you can convert mp3 or wav files into Data URI format:

https://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php

Comment: Works fine on Chrome, but not on Firefox (v 30.0)

Comment: If I paste this in as a snippet in Chrome developer tools, it works the first time I run it. But subsequent runs fail.

Comment: I also have this issue, it works just once and then it's silent.

Comment: The Audio is read once but not set at the beginning, use snd.currentTime = 0; to set the audio file to the beginning before calling play. Then, you can play the sound with the same instance.

Comment: Why not store the base64 string in a separate file and give it an appropriate extension.... oh wait, that's an audio file!

Comment: Not work with Opera 42, Also caniuse say yes. I used the example posted in  question http://jsfiddle.net/7EAgz/ . Why not work in Opera?

Comment: Solve change type data to data:audio/mp3;base64, 
Replace wav to mp3

Comment: Not working in Safari or Chrome on the IPhone. Works on Chrome and IE11

Comment: Refused to load media from 'data:audio/wav;base64,...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src https://etc.net https://*.etc.net".

Comment: gives me his warning: Autoplay is only allowed when approved by the user, the site is activated by the user, or media is muted.

Comment: Is there are way to add to this function, so that each time it is called, it stops any previous 'beeps' from playing? I.e., to prevent overlapping sounds from occurring if the beep is called twice in quick succession.

Comment: Jamie, I did not test it, but if you just have `snd` as a global variable it should work as you describe if you start the function with `snd.stop()`

Answer (score 147):

```
/*if you want to beep without using a wave file*/
var context = new AudioContext();
var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = "sine";
oscillator.frequency.value = 800;
oscillator.connect(context.destination);
oscillator.start();
// Beep for 500 milliseconds
setTimeout(function () {
    oscillator.stop();
}, 100);
```

The top answer was correct at the time but is now wrong; you can do it in pure javascript. But the one answer using javascript doesn't work any more, and the other answers are pretty limited or don't use pure javascript.

I made my own solution that works well and lets you control the volume, frequency, and wavetype.

```
//if you have another AudioContext class use that one, as some browsers have a limit
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.audioContext);

//All arguments are optional:

//duration of the tone in milliseconds. Default is 500
//frequency of the tone in hertz. default is 440
//volume of the tone. Default is 1, off is 0.
//type of tone. Possible values are sine, square, sawtooth, triangle, and custom. Default is sine.
//callback to use on end of tone
function beep(duration, frequency, volume, type, callback) {
    var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
    var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
    
    oscillator.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    
    if (volume){gainNode.gain.value = volume;}
    if (frequency){oscillator.frequency.value = frequency;}
    if (type){oscillator.type = type;}
    if (callback){oscillator.onended = callback;}
    
    oscillator.start(audioCtx.currentTime);
    oscillator.stop(audioCtx.currentTime + ((duration || 500) / 1000));
};
```

Someone suggested I edit this to note it only works on some browsers. However [Audiocontext seems to be supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=audiocontext) on all modern browsers, as far as I can tell. It isn't supported on IE, but that has been discontinued by Microsoft. If you have any issues with this on a specific browser please report it.

Comment: Opera 12.17: `Unhandled Error: 'window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext' is not a constructor `
Last Chrome: ok

Comment: That's weird. I added "window.audioContext" (lowercase) which might work.

Comment: The same `Unhandled Error: 'window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.audioContext' is not a constructor`

Comment: I found the issue, Opera 12 doesn't support the AudioContext interface. Only Opera 15 does.

Comment: I do stand by my statement that the top answer is wrong about it not being possible to do directly in javascript. Clearly this shows that it is.

Comment: On firefox, this gives me: `InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable`

Comment: I pasted the code on Chrome's console and tested the function. It only works with sine, with all other options it says: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'AudioParam': The provided float value is non-finite.
    at beep (<anonymous>:18:37)
    at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: For a Promise-base solution instead of a callback, make the function async, remove the callback parameter, replace the line that sets `onended` with `const promise = new Promise(resolve => {oscillator.onended = resolve})` and return the promise from the function. You can then `await beep()` and it will return control to your function after the sound concludes.

Answer (score 88):

I wrote a function to beep with the new Audio API.

```
var beep = (function () {
    var ctxClass = window.audioContext ||window.AudioContext || window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext
    var ctx = new ctxClass();
    return function (duration, type, finishedCallback) {

        duration = +duration;

        // Only 0-4 are valid types.
        type = (type % 5) || 0;

        if (typeof finishedCallback != "function") {
            finishedCallback = function () {};
        }

        var osc = ctx.createOscillator();

        osc.type = type;
        //osc.type = "sine";

        osc.connect(ctx.destination);
        if (osc.noteOn) osc.noteOn(0); // old browsers
        if (osc.start) osc.start(); // new browsers

        setTimeout(function () {
            if (osc.noteOff) osc.noteOff(0); // old browsers
            if (osc.stop) osc.stop(); // new browsers
            finishedCallback();
        }, duration);

    };
})();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55Kfu/1506/).

Comment: Unfortunately, this code can not be run twice on Chrome :( Exception "audio resources unavailable for AudioContext construction" has been raised

Comment: @aavezel that's not true, it can run multiple times

Comment: duration is coming out as NaN if not supplied. Also, why not just use "beep : function(duration, type, finishedCallback)"? Apart from that it works well, thanks.

Comment: @CpnCrunch Just saves creating a new audio context for each invocation. Duration wasn't meant to be optional, but you could `duration = +duration || 0;` to fix that (or even `duration | 0`, which would also drop negatives and fractional portions).

Comment: You should replace osc.noteOn(0) with osc.start(0). Also, replace the timeout with osc.stop(ctx.currentTime+duration/1000). The problem with the timeout is that it takes between 0.5s and 6s for the audio to actually start playing on Chrome the first time you use it (due to lazy instantiation of AudioContext), so the timeout can fire before the beep has started.

Comment: Oh, and you should check window.audioContext || window.webkitAudioContext for null, otherwise it will crash on IE when it tries to do a new(null).

Comment: [Here's](http://mdn.github.io/violent-theremin/) some working demo. And the source is located [here](https://github.com/mdn/violent-theremin/blob/gh-pages/scripts/app.js). It's from MDN documentation page.

Comment: This no longer works in Chrome. It used to, and now my beeping app no longer works. Any idea how to fix/replace it?

Comment: I read the documentation of the audio API and wrote my own better version posted below.

Answer (score 84):

Using [Houshalter's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29641185/642706), I made this simple tone synthesizer demo.

## Screenshot

Here is a screenshot. Try the live demo further down in this Answer (click *Run code snippet*).

[image: screenshot of live demo available further down in this Answer]

## Demo code

```js
audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

show();

function show() {
  frequency = document.getElementById("fIn").value;
  document.getElementById("fOut").innerHTML = frequency + ' Hz';

  switch (document.getElementById("tIn").value * 1) {
    case 0: type = 'sine'; break;
    case 1: type = 'square'; break;
    case 2: type = 'sawtooth'; break;
    case 3: type = 'triangle'; break;
  }
  document.getElementById("tOut").innerHTML = type;

  volume = document.getElementById("vIn").value / 100;
  document.getElementById("vOut").innerHTML = volume;

  duration = document.getElementById("dIn").value;
  document.getElementById("dOut").innerHTML = duration + ' ms';
}

function beep() {
  var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
  var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();

  oscillator.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

  gainNode.gain.value = volume;
  oscillator.frequency.value = frequency;
  oscillator.type = type;

  oscillator.start();

  setTimeout(
    function() {
      oscillator.stop();
    },
    duration
  );
};
```

```html
frequency
<input type="range" id="fIn" min="40" max="6000" oninput="show()" />
<span id="fOut"></span><br>
type
<input type="range" id="tIn" min="0" max="3" oninput="show()" />
<span id="tOut"></span><br>
volume
<input type="range" id="vIn" min="0" max="100" oninput="show()" />
<span id="vOut"></span><br>
duration
<input type="range" id="dIn" min="1" max="5000" oninput="show()" />
<span id="dOut"></span>
<br>
<button onclick='beep();'>Play</button>
```

You can clone and tweak the code here:
[Tone synthesizer demo on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/tupoyi/4/edit?html,js,output)

Have fun!

### Compatible browsers:

- Chrome mobile & desktop
- Firefox mobile & desktop
- Opera mobile, mini & desktop
- Android browser
- Microsoft Edge browser
- Safari on iPhone or iPad

### Not Compatible

- Internet Explorer version 11 (but does work on the Edge browser)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 48):

As we read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1934325/456584), HTML5 will solve this for you if you're open to that route. HTML5 audio is supported in [all modern browsers](http://html5readiness.com/).

Here's a copy of the example:

```
var snd = new Audio("file.wav"); // buffers automatically when created
snd.play();
```

Comment: Hooray, finally one that works in Firefox, both desktop and Android

Answer (score 47):

This will enable you to play the sound multiple times, in contrast to the top-voted answer:

```
var playSound = (function beep() {
    var snd = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64,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");  
    return function() {     
        snd.play(); 
    }
})();

playSound(); // Play first time
playSound(); // Play second time
```

Comment: Refused to load media from 'data:audio/wav;base64,...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src https://etc.net https://*.etc.net".

Answer (score 24):

Now it easy enough with JavaScript [AudioContext API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/AudioContext). It [fully supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=AudioContext) by major desktop and mobile web browsers...

```
let context = null;

const beep = (freq = 520, duration = 200, vol = 100) => {
    const oscillator = context.createOscillator();
    const gain = context.createGain();
    oscillator.connect(gain);
    oscillator.frequency.value = freq;
    oscillator.type = "square";
    gain.connect(context.destination);
    gain.gain.value = vol * 0.01;
    oscillator.start(context.currentTime);
    oscillator.stop(context.currentTime + duration * 0.001);
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    context = new AudioContext();
    beep();
});
```

I wrote a small application that plays music from the Mario game without any audio file, just runtime. In my opinion it’s interesting, you can see the [source code](https://gist.github.com/tripolskypetr/a793967504aa6fcc0d3ebb30d1642dec) and listen it.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Using CSS you can do it if you add the following style to a tag, but you will need a `wav` file:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .beep {cue: url("beep.wav") }
</style>

var body=document.getElementByTagName("body");
body.className=body.className + " " + "beep";
```

Comment: Can you explain that a bit? Or prepare a simple fiddle!

Answer (score 6):

This code supports sequencing of multiple beeps, as well as gradual change in frequency ('ramp' flag). Both examples are given below.

```html
<script>
var audioContext = null;
var oscillatorNode = null;
var stopTime = 0;

function beep (frequency, durationSec, ramp=false)
{
    if (oscillatorNode == null) {
        audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext) ();
        stopTime = audioContext.currentTime;

        oscillatorNode = audioContext.createOscillator();
        oscillatorNode.type = "sine";
        oscillatorNode.connect (audioContext.destination);
        if (ramp) {
            oscillatorNode.frequency.setValueAtTime (frequency, stopTime);
        }
        oscillatorNode.start ();
        oscillatorNode.onended = function() {
            oscillatorNode = null;
            audioContext = null;
        }
    }

    if (ramp) {
        oscillatorNode.frequency.linearRampToValueAtTime (frequency, stopTime); // value in hertz
    } else {
        oscillatorNode.frequency.setValueAtTime (frequency, stopTime);  // value in hertz
    }

    stopTime += durationSec;
    oscillatorNode.stop (stopTime);
}
function test1()
{
        beep (250, 0.5);
        beep (1000, 0.2);
        beep (550, 0.5);
}
    
function test2()
{
        beep (50, 2, true);
        beep (5000, 2, true);
        beep (50, 0, true);
}
</script>
    
<button onclick='test1()'>Beep!</button>
<button onclick='test2()'>Beep(ramped)!</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I get it to beep using HTML5:
First I copy and convert the windows wav file to mp3, then I use this code:

```
var _beep = window.Audio("Content/Custom/Beep.mp3")

function playBeep() { _beep.play()};
```

It's faster to declare the sound file globally and refer to it as needed.

Comment: simple and neat solution, this worked for me. thanks for saving me the stress of writing lots of audio lib code

Comment: Actually it doesn't work here. `window.Audio("https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-07.mp3")` returns an error: `VM1487:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Audio': Please use the 'new' operator`

Answer (score 3):

There's no crossbrowser way to achieve this with pure javascript. Instead you could use a small .wav file that you play using embed or object tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
function beep(wavFile){
    wavFile = wavFile || "beep.wav"
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
        var e = document.createElement('BGSOUND');
        e.src = wavFile;
        e.loop =1;
        document.body.appendChild(e);
        document.body.removeChild(e);
    }else{
        var e = document.createElement('AUDIO');
        var src1 = document.createElement('SOURCE');
        src1.type= 'audio/wav';
        src1.src= wavFile;
        e.appendChild(src1);
        e.play();
    }
}
```

Works on Chrome,IE,Mozilla using Win7 OS.
Requires a `beep.wav` file on the server.

Comment: Very nice! This is the solution that worked here from all the other ones! I used this link to as the `wavFile` source: `https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-07.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

```
function Sound(url, vol, autoplay, loop)
{
    var that = this;

    that.url = (url === undefined) ? "" : url;
    that.vol = (vol === undefined) ? 1.0 : vol;
    that.autoplay = (autoplay === undefined) ? true : autoplay;
    that.loop = (loop === undefined) ? false : loop;
    that.sample = null;

    if(that.url !== "")
    {
        that.sync = function(){
            that.sample.volume = that.vol;
            that.sample.loop = that.loop;
            that.sample.autoplay = that.autoplay;
            setTimeout(function(){ that.sync(); }, 60);
        };

        that.sample = document.createElement("audio");
        that.sample.src = that.url;
        that.sync();

        that.play = function(){
            if(that.sample)
            {
                that.sample.play();
            }
        };

        that.pause = function(){
            if(that.sample)
            {
                that.sample.pause();
            }
        };
    }
}

var test = new Sound("http://mad-hatter.fr/Assets/projects/FreedomWings/Assets/musiques/freedomwings.mp3");
test.play();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sv9j638j/

Answer (score 0):

Note:put this code in your javascript at the point you want the beep to occur.
and remember to specify the directory or folder where the beep sound is stored(source).

```html
<script>
//Appending HTML5 Audio Tag in HTML Body
$('<audio id="chatAudio"><source src="sound/notify.ogg" type="audio/ogg"><source src="sound/notify.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><source src="sound/notify.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>').appendTo('body');

$('#chatAudio')[0].play();
</script>
```

Reference:http://www.9lessons.info/2013/04/play-notification-sound-using-jquery.html.

I implemented this in a social media i am developing and it works find, a notification like that of facebook when chatting, notifying you that you have a new chat message

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src='https://surikov.github.io/webaudiofont/npm/dist/WebAudioFontPlayer.js'></script>
    <script src='https://surikov.github.io/webaudiofontdata/sound/0000_JCLive_sf2_file.js'></script>
    <script>
        var selectedPreset=_tone_0000_JCLive_sf2_file;
        var AudioContextFunc = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        var audioContext = new AudioContextFunc();
        var player=new WebAudioFontPlayer();
        player.loader.decodeAfterLoading(audioContext, '_tone_0000_JCLive_sf2_file');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a href="#" onmousedown="player.queueWaveTable(audioContext, audioContext.destination, selectedPreset, 0, 55, 3.5);">Play a note</a></p>
    <hr/>
    <p><a href="https://github.com/surikov/webaudiofont">source</a></p>
</body>
```

listen here
https://jsbin.com/lamidog/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

```js
function beep(freq = 660, duration = 90, vol = 50) {
  var context = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
  const oscillator = context.createOscillator();
  const gain = context.createGain();
  gain.gain.setValueAtTime(0, context.currentTime);
  gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1, context.currentTime + 0.002);
  oscillator.connect(gain);
  oscillator.frequency.value = freq;
  oscillator.type = "square";
  gain.connect(context.destination);
  oscillator.start(context.currentTime);
  oscillator.stop(context.currentTime + duration * .001);
  oscillator.onended = () => context.close();
}
```

```html
<br>
<center><button onclick="beep()">Beep!</button></center>
```

Answer (score -3):

You need a sound file to be served from somewhere.  Here's the code from [Scriptaculous](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/downloads)'s Sound library:

```
//Default:
<embed style="height:0" id="sound_#{track}_#{id}" src="#{url}" loop="false" autostart="true" hidden="true"/>

//For Gecko:
if(Prototype.Browser.Gecko && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Win") > 0){
  if(navigator.plugins && $A(navigator.plugins).detect(function(p){ return p.name.indexOf('QuickTime') != -1 }))
    Sound.template = new Template('<object id="sound_#{track}_#{id}" width="0" height="0" type="audio/mpeg" data="#{url}"/>');
  else if(navigator.plugins && $A(navigator.plugins).detect(function(p){ return p.name.indexOf('Windows Media') != -1 }))
    Sound.template = new Template('<object id="sound_#{track}_#{id}" type="application/x-mplayer2" data="#{url}"></object>');
  else if(navigator.plugins && $A(navigator.plugins).detect(function(p){ return p.name.indexOf('RealPlayer') != -1 }))
    Sound.template = new Template('<embed type="audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin" style="height:0" id="sound_#{track}_#{id}" src="#{url}" loop="false" autostart="true" hidden="true"/>');
  else
    Sound.play = function(){};
}
```