# Playing a sound in safari

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am trying to play a sound in Safari on a special event.
This is what I am doing

```
<html>
    <head>
        <in a js file>
            if(event)
                document.getElementById('sound').play();
        </in a js file>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <audio id="sound" src="pling.mp3"></audio> 
    </body>
</html>
```

The sound pling.mp3 is in the the same folder as the html file.

The result in Safari developer console is:
TypeError: Result of expression 'document.getElementById('sound').play' [undefined] is not a function.

What am I doing wrong?
Isn't this the way it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
document.getElementById('sound')[0].play();
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use the [Audio API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/video.html#htmlmediaelement), as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933969/sound-effects-in-javascript-html5), to play sound effects after certain events. In my opinion the audio tag is more suited for songs can be played, stopped and controlled via the UI. If you do use `audio` tags, you must pause and rewind before it can be played again. You can use [this script](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/soundlink.shtml) which does that automatically.

If you want to play audio for example on hover events, do something like this in jQuery:

```
// iterate through the elements that must have audio applied on hover
$('.audio_effect').each(function() {
  $(this).on('mouseover', function() {
    new Audio('path-to-audiofile.mp3').play();
  });
});
```

Since you can't play an Audio element again without resetting its internal pointer, the easiest course of action is to just create the element fresh on every hover, like I am doing above.

Comment: Update: apparently IE9 and lower do not support the `new Audio()` constructor. The most cross-platform solution is to create `audio` elements using document.createElement().

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect, as you can of course do this with the audio element and the Media API, as that's what it's there for.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks so much for the downvote. I do understand that the sound can play once by using an `audio` tag and the code you provided. But in order to play the sound again you must rewind it. Your answer will do no good when the event fires again. I will update my answer to reflect that.