# Unable to adjust audio volume

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I'm trying to do what I thought was a very simple thing but, having searched the web, it seems not.

I'm using a free audio player 'audiojs' in conjunction with HTML5 audio to play an audio track and that all works fine. However, what I want to do is to set the audio volume to a low level initially, leaving the users able to increase it if they want to using the normal player slider.

I expected there would be an attribute like

`<audio volume="low">` or `<audio volume="0.5">`

but there doesn't seem to be one. If it has to be done with Javascript, I would want to use jQuery.

Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the loudness of HTML5 audio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075909/how-to-set-the-loudness-of-html5-audio)

Comment: I read that but didn't fully understand it. I tried it but it didn't work so I probably got it wrong. I don't understand javascript but how would you code it in jQuery starting with `$('audio').something();`?

Answer (score 0):

With a HTML5 element, you can set the volume in javascript in the following way:

```
document.getElementById('audio-control').volume = 0.2;
```

Where the id is the id attribute on the audio control.

Here's an example of this in action:

http://jsbin.com/cezutiyuroxi/1/edit?html,js,output