# How do I see HTML Audio noise volume

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

How do I see HTML Audio noise volume, I am not talking about the volume output level but the noise level that the audio element is currently playing.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API --- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext 
  ----  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075909/how-to-set-the-loudness-of-html5-audio

Comment: mplungjan I am talking about getting the volume of what is playing not playing at certain volumes

Comment: I can only think what you are looking for is in one of the pages referred here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext or not possible

Comment: You need to clarify this question. What do you define as 'noise level'? There is no 'noise level' property for any HTML audio.

Comment: Keno Clayton - I am trying to get how loud an audio element is at a certain time. for example a quiet room would be a 0 while a crowded stadium would be a 8. Something like this.

Answer (score -1):

Please do like this

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: This is just an example of the audio element, I need to know how to see the loudness of the audio currently playing.