# Play multiple sound at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Using HTML 5, I want to play multiple sounds simultaneously. how can I do it?

Here's what I currently have:

```html
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="audio/(TESBIHAT).mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="audio/Dombra.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />

    <embed height="50px" width="100px" src="audio/(TESBIHAT).mp3" />
    <embed height="50px" width="100px" src="audio/Dombra.mp3" />
</audio>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933969/sound-effects-in-javascript-html5

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With JavaScript and the HTML5 Audio API you could do something like this:

```
var snd1  = new Audio();
var src1  = document.createElement("source");
src1.type = "audio/mpeg";
src1.src  = "audio/Dombra.mp3";
snd1.appendChild(src1);

var snd2  = new Audio();
var src2  = document.createElement("source");
src2.type = "audio/mpeg";
src2.src  = "audio/(TESBIHAT).mp3";
snd2.appendChild(src2);

snd1.play(); snd2.play(); // Now both will play at the same time
```

I have tested this in Chrome v. 20, and it seems to work :)

The `<source>` tag is used to specify different formats of the same file - such that the browser can choose another format as fallback in case the first one is not supported. That is why your own suggested solution does not work.

Comment: Thanks for reply Chrome and IE work but only n't  working Opera not important thanks :)

Comment: It won't work in Opera because it doesn't support mp3. Use .ogg instead http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/

Comment: Will this work on mobile devices that only support one audio stream at a time?

Comment: Can you do it without creating elements?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. Shows `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException`

Comment: @ArvindK. the browser will show that when it prevents a sound from auto-playing, there might not be any problem with your code. See [this information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API#Controlling_sound) from the MDN which is relevant (even though it's talking about the Web Audio API). **TL;DR:** Click on your page before the sound tries to play and you probably won't get that error.

Comment: Doesn't work well on mobile devices