# html5/javascript audio play multiple tracks at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, web-audio-api

Is it possible to play the whole audio instance at the same time?

I know, I could create every time a new instance and call `.play()` on every instance, but I think it's dirty.

```
sound1 = new Audio('sound1.mp3');  
sound2 = new Audio('sound2.mp3');  
sound1.play();  
sound2.play();
```

It's more or less the same as in this thread: [Play multiple sound at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652197/play-multiple-sound-at-the-same-time)

But there has to be a more elegant way?

Answer (score 6):

**Edit: `MediaController` and `mediagroup` turned out to be vaporware. You will want to stick with the "dirty" way to do it, at least for now, as there is no official syncing solution.**

<s>The proper way to play multiple audio or video objects synchronously is to use the `mediagroup` attribute and the corresponding `MediaController` object. See the article ["HTML5 multi-track audio or video"](http://gingertech.net/2011/05/01/html5-multi-track-audio-or-video/):</s>

> [A]n attribute called [@mediagroup](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#attr-media-mediagroup) can be added in markup to slave multiple media elements together. This is administrated in the JavaScript API through a [MediaController](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#synchronising-multiple-media-elements) object, which provides events and attributes for the combined multi-track object.

Set both audio files to a single `mediagroup`. When a media element is assigned to a `mediagroup`, a `MediaController` is created for that group. Use the `play()` method on that controller and all media elements in the group will play synchronously.

Programmatically, you can assign a `mediagroup` like so, and then from that point trigger `play()` on the `MediaController` from any one of the slave media elements, like so:

```
sound1 = new Audio('sound1.mp3');
sound2 = new Audio('sound2.mp3');
sound1.mediaGroup = 'soundGroup';
sound2.mediaGroup = 'soundGroup';
sound1.controller.play();
```

(Sources: w3school.com's HTML Audio/Video DOM [mediaGroup Property page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_mediagroup.asp), [controller Property page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_controller.asp), [play() Method page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp), and [the standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#synchronising-multiple-media-elements))

*NOTE: I haven't tested the above code; please, if you can confirm that this code is not standard-compliant and does not function as expected, let us know. Be aware that you are looking at a very new aspect of the HTML5 standard, and this being the case, **do not expect broad browser compatibility. (as of January 2014)***

Comment: thanks for sharing! tried out the code but I figuerd out that the conroller isnt supported in any major browser

Comment: You do not need the controller element. Just `sound1.play();`

Comment: Firefox [hasn't implement](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=847377) neither `MediaController` nor `mediaGroup`, and Chromium has [unshipped it](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/MVcoNSPs1UQ).

Comment: This answer should probably be deleted again - At the time of writing it was a draft-only experimental feature, and it got killed off, so this is _never_ going to be a proper answer to the question on how to do what the question was about. At best, current and future visitors to SO won't find this answer, but at worst they do and find instructions on doing something that can't ever work.