# play multiple sounds simultaneously in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

Is there any way to play 2 audio files simultaneously? I have an audio file that will be played in a loop and while this sound plays, I'm trying to play another sound. I was expecting that both of them will be played simultaneously, but it looks like both sounds are placed in a sequence, that only one sound can be played at a time

Comment: checkout how to ask, you are missing a lot of information we need to help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652197/play-multiple-sound-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) constructor

```
const music = new Audio('myPathTo/music.mp3')
const soundEffects = new Audio('myPathTo/effects.mp3')
```

and then

```
music.play()
soundEffects.play()
```