# JavaScript/HTML5 Guitar, Playing a different sound for each string

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a link to my code: http://jsbin.com/ebadic/9/edit

It is from a demo I found here (this links explains how it works, the part i'm using is at the bottom):

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/jamwithchrome-interaction/

It creates 6 guitar strings. What I would like to do is have a sound play when one of the 6 strings is moused over - A different sound for each string, or a single sound that is pitched up/down for each string (perhaps using the playbackRate attribute)

My code already plays a sound when I mouseover a single string, but the problem is that it plays the same sound for each one. How do I make it play a DIFFERENT SOUND for each string?

Comment: If you know how to play any sound, why are you not able to play different sounds?

Comment: Because I add in the ability to play a sound here:       
      GuitarString.prototype.strum = function() {
        this._strumForce = 5;
        document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();

      };  and that makes it so the sound plays on every string. I don't know where in the code I could add a different sound for each string, or make my same sound pitch up for each new string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `strum()` here:

```
Stage.prototype.checkPoint = function(x, y, zone) {
    if(zone.inside(x, y)) {
        zone.string.strum();
    }
};
```

Why not add an `<audio>` identifier here?
I suppose the sound you want to play depends on the x and y coordinates?

```
Stage.prototype.checkPoint = function(x, y, zone) {
    if(zone.inside(x, y)) {
        zone.string.strum(getAudioID(x, y));
    }
};
```

How you fill in the `getAudioID(x, y)` is up to you (I am no musician, so I really do not know :) )

Of course you'd need to change the `strum()` method as well to something like this:

```
GuitarString.prototype.strum = function(audioID) {
    this._strumForce = 5;
    document.getElementById(audioID).play();
};
```

(Up to here fits nicely into your current design.)

---

A better approach is to add the `audioID` to your `GuitarString` class when you instantiate the guitar string objects. So each guitar string (object) uses its own audio track.

Even though this would require some bigger modifications to your code, I would advice to do it this way as it results in much clear and understandable code!

---

Also checkout [Sound effects in JavaScript / HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933969/sound-effects-in-javascript-html5#1934325) it shows how you can play audio tracks without using the `<audio>`-tag. This is particular useful when you have many audio fragments!