# Break string into chars and attach sounds to each char using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, html, css

I have have a string stored in a MySQL database.

I want to pull the string from the database, break it into `char` elements and attach sound files to each letter. The letters will be displayed in a web page and when clicked, will play a sound which represents that letter.

I have tried using the `.split()` function, but have not had much success. Has anyone seen anything similar to this or does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you paste what you tried?  Are you just trying to break up : 'whatagreatsong' into w h a t ... ?

Comment: Showing us your could make it easy to suggest solution. Why split did not help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var char = [],
    str, // your string
    i,
    len = str.length
for (i = 0; i < len ; i++){
    char[i] = str.charAt(i);
}

// now you have an array of characters

// setup event handlers for the click action

// setup audio output
```

Comment: This seems very helpful. 
If I break 'AND' into 'A' 'N' 'D'. How could I attach the correct sound to each char dynamically?

Somthing like, 

   if(char[i] == ('a'){
        char[i].playclip(a)
   }

Am I roughly on the right track? Sorry, Im pretty new to javaScript.

Comment: you said "when clicked" so you would need to set up event handlers for a click event.  Also you need need to setup and element for each letter.

Answer (score 1):

If I look here

[Sound effects in JavaScript / HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933969/sound-effects-in-javascript-html5)

you can try

```
var chars = "<? echo $string; ?>".split("");
var sounds = [];
$.each(chars,function(i,char) {

  if (!sounds[char]) sounds[char] = new Audio(char+".wav"); // buffers automatically when created
  $("#container").append('<a href="#" onclick="sounds[this.innerHTML].play();return false">'+char+'</a>');
});
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and explain how this answers the question?

Comment: I've always thought avoiding automatic flagging due to length is a good thing.

Comment: Your answer, originally, was flagged by bots for being too short. Probably because of the answer being 100% one code block. The traits of a good answer is show and tell, not just show.

Answer (score 0):

To pull of the split its relatively simple, you can use traditional JS, or jQuery, all you need to do is plug in your markup generation to the below.

```
var str = "No clue what you are trying";
for (var x = 0; x < str.length; x++){
    var myC = str.charAt(x);
    //or var myC = str[x];
    //what do you want to do?
}

//jQuery overkill
$.each(
    str.split(''),
    function( idx, myC ){
        //what do you want to do?
    };
);
```

Comment: I'm afraid that playing a song is not a synchronous operation => your approach won't work.