# how can-i manipulate sound (<audio>) in javascript cross-browser?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, effects

I am using  API from HTML5, it's realy cool but how can I add effects to my sounds?

Example:

1) add reverb

2) increase or decrease basses or acutes

3) control panoramic sound (left / right)

It's possible to do that? How? Is there a library for doing that, which is crossbrowser?

Thank you.

Comment: The WebAudio API has limited compatibility at the moment.  Be sure to check out the features compatibility, if it matters to you.

Comment: nothing new about that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sound effects in JavaScript / HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933969/sound-effects-in-javascript-html5)