# Looping sound onclick just

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

i'm developing a online drum pad site, and i have few problems, one of them is :
I want repeat the kick when the user clicking on more then one time on the same time "like click click click and the kick repeating each time Faster"
like a real **drumpad**! 
my Javascript code is :

```
<script>

var kick1 = new Audio("kick1.mp3");
var kick2 = new Audio("kick2.mp3");
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if(keyCode == 81) {
        kick1.play();

    }
       var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if(keyCode == 87) {
        kick2.play();
    } 
};

</script>
```

My Html is this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Loops pad online</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsebar" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsebar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</header>
<div class="clear">
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron fixed-jmb">
    <div class="container" id="padpa">  
     <button type="button" onclick="kick1.play();"
     class="btn btn-default cube-call">808Kick<br><kbd>Q</kbd></button>
     <button type="button" onclick="kick2.play();" class="btn btn-default cube-call">Chromo Kick<br><kbd>W</kbd></button>

</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My css : Bootstrap

Comment: What's it currently doing?

Comment: For example when you click on Q it's will make a kick sound, my problem is i want click more then one time on Q to make more the kick sound, like this for other...

Answer (score 0):

Quick refactor, might fix you issue:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  switch(e.keyCode) {
    case 81:
        var kick1 = new Audio("kick1.mp3");
        kick1.play();
        break;
    case 87:
        var kick2 = new Audio("play.mp3");
        kick2.play();
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Key not bound!");
  }
};
```

Taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1934325/1179430).

Comment: Made a change, give it a shot.