# Beep in Vaadin app

Tags: javascript, java, audio, vaadin, beep

I want a small short beep noise to get the user's attention occasionally in my Vaadin Framework 8 app.

Example usage: Beep when password entered into a user-authentication page fails to authenticate successfully. User clicks "Sign-in" button, beep happens immediately after the password check flunks.

Another example: When an [automatically updated](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html) [chart](https://vaadin.com/charts) trends upward significantly, play 3 beeps in ascending frequency (notes). If chart trends downward, play descending frequency (notes).

I would like to avoid downloading a sound file to the web client, unless that has clear advantages. Seems simpler, lightweight, and hopefully higher performance to use JavaScript or HTML5 to generate a beep on the client itself locally.

I found what looks like a modern JavaScript solution in this [Answer by Houshalter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29641185/642706). And this [sibling Answer by CaptainWiz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41077092/642706) contains a live demo that seems to work well.

- Is there a way to trigger the client-side execution of this JavaScript code from my server-side Vaadin app’s Java code?
- Will it be performant? I mean the beep needs to happen very quickly in the context of the user's current action, without an annoying/confusing time delay.

Alternatively, [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1934325/642706) talks about HTML5 having a new Audio objects feature for playing a sound file. Might that have advantages over invoking a chunk of JavaScript code for sound synthesis?

And another alternative: *WebAudio* API by W3C as shown in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11550773/642706).

Comment: What is the (class of) "context of the current action"?  Should it beep when the user enters a letter in a number field?  or should it beep if some new message arrived?

Comment: @cfrick Example usage: Beep when password entered into a user-authentication page fails to authenticate successfully. User clicks "Sign-in" button, beep happens immediately after the password check flunks.

Answer (score 4):

One way to achieve this via an [`AbstractJavascriptComponent`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.6/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractJavaScriptComponent.html) in Vaadin.  This
gives a rather direct approach to write Javascript components or make JS libs
accessible without spending too much time on getting a grasp on GWT etc.

The `callFunction` from an `AbstractJavascriptComponent` calls directly into
the JS-code in the browser.

Create a Beeper class:

```
package app.ui
import com.vaadin.annotations.JavaScript
import com.vaadin.ui.AbstractJavaScriptComponent
@JavaScript("js/beeper_connector.js")
class Beeper extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent {
    void beep(Integer duration, Integer frequency) {
        callFunction('beep', duration, frequency)
    }
}
```

Note the annotation and also create that file in the same package (`app.ui`),
on that path with that name (`js/beeper_connector.js`).  The file needs at
least to contain a "class" with the name `app_ui_Beeper` (FQN of the Java class
with the dots replaced by underscores) Add your `beep` function with params of
types, that can be transported via "JSON":

```
window.app_ui_Beeper = function() {
    var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.audioContext);
    this.beep = function(duration, frequency) {
        var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
        var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
        oscillator.connect(gainNode);
        gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        if (frequency){oscillator.frequency.value = frequency;}
        oscillator.start();
        setTimeout(function(){oscillator.stop()}, (duration ? duration : 500));
    };
};
```

**This code is lifted from the answer referenced by OP: [How do I make Javascript beep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep/29641185#29641185)**

Now make sure, that you add a `Beeper` instance somewhere in your main scene
graph in the UI, so it can be accessed from everywhere.

A working example can be found here: https://github.com/christoph-frick/vaadin-webaudio-beep