# Generating Sound in OBIEE

Tags: oracle11g, obiee

Is it possible to generate a sound using an agent or some other method when a certain condition is met, and if so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could add javascript and HTML5 audio objects into a Narrative in an OBIEE analysis report.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933969/sound-effects-in-javascript-html5) is a link on how to add sound using HTML5 audio objects.

[Here](https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2013/06/embedding-a-d3-visualisation-in-obiee/) is a link to how to add javascript into a Narrative in OBIEE using D3 as an example.