# Why do we write out.println() in jsp instead of System.out.println()?

Tags: java, jsp

I started learning jsp and I am seeing that, if we want to print something in jsp,we have to write `out.println()` instead of `System.out.println()`, but if we write `System.out.println()` it does not show any error but does not o/p to the browser also. I want to know why it happens? As all we know that `System` is a predefined class and `out` is the output stream connected to the console. So why we do not require to write `System` in jsp?
Thanks.

Comment: simple answer: because you want to write to the web page, not the server's console

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because the `out` we're referring to isn't `System.out`, it's a variable in the effective method that wraps our JSP page. `System.out` writes to the servlet container's console (usually a log file); `out` is a different class entirely which writes to the output stream for the generated response.

When a JSP is turned into code, it (in theory, and with Tomcat, in fact) goes through two steps: JSP -> servlet source code, then servlet source code -> class. The entire page is put inside a method, which with Tomcat looks something like this:

```
public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {

    PageContext pageContext = null;
    HttpSession session = null;
    ServletContext application = null;
    ServletConfig config = null;
    JspWriter out = null;
    Object page = this;
    JspWriter _jspx_out = null;
    PageContext _jspx_page_context = null;

    try {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        pageContext = _jspxFactory.getPageContext(this, request, response,
                  "qdforumerror.jsp", true, 65536, true);
        _jspx_page_context = pageContext;
        application = pageContext.getServletContext();
        config = pageContext.getServletConfig();
        session = pageContext.getSession();
        out = pageContext.getOut();
        _jspx_out = out;

        /* =============================================
           ...your <% ... %> JSP code here, with
           any markup outside those tags converted into
           out.print("..."); statments...
           =============================================
        */
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        if (!(t instanceof SkipPageException)){
            out = _jspx_out;
            if (out != null && out.getBufferSize() != 0)
                try { out.clearBuffer(); } catch (java.io.IOException e) {}
            if (_jspx_page_context != null) _jspx_page_context.handlePageException(t);
        }
      }
      finally {
          _jspxFactory.releasePageContext(_jspx_page_context);
    }
}
```

As you can see, `out` is a variable within that method, of type `JspWriter` (rather than `OutputStream` as with `System.out`).

(Side note: Code you include in `<%! ... %>` tags rather than the normal `<% ... %>` tags isn't put in the method; it's put elsewhere in the generated servlet class.)

Comment: In core java out is a variable of PrintStream class, in jsp it is a variable of JspWriter and in servlet it is of type PrintWriter, its little confusing.

Comment: @Debabratta: `System.out` and the `out` used in JSPs have nothing to do with one another, they just have the same name. I don't know why `JspWriter` is used in JSPs instead of `PrintWriter`. I suspect it has to do with taglibs. But fundamentally, console apps (using `System.out`) are quite different from JSPs, and JSPs are a bit different from servlets, so...

Answer (score 14):

The `out` in jsp is a [`JspWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter.html) object which is created by Jsp automatically, it is used to write something to webpage while `System.out.print()` is used to output/write something to the console.

Comment: A `JspWriter`, not a `PrintWriter`.

Comment: Can you please edit the reply? Please also add this link as the source: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter.html. I don't why but I cannot see the edit button on this reply.

Comment: @MonsterTruck: You can't edit other people's posts until you have 2,000 rep, although I thought you could *propose* edits. If we're going to add a link (which I've done), we'd want to link to something up to date. It's been six years since Java EE 1.4 was superceded by Java EE 5, which has since been superceded by 6! ;-)

Comment: @Crowder, I should raise this on the meta site but I see an edit link on every reply except this one :S. Right about the version. Google should update their search algos to better handle document versions --most C# classes you google for give 3.0 results and Java classes give 1.4 results. Thanks for making that edit.