# Why won't my JDBC (read) query work on my JSP page?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, maven, jdbc

I wrote a .jsp page as part of a larger databse project.  The goal is to have a series of .jsp pages which use java and html to display data from a mySQL database.  I am having an issue with JDBC queries, in particular using prepared statements to select a car model from my inventory table.  I have coded it so that a the car with id = 3 will return the corresponding car model, and then print it on the screen.  After I run the code, there is no output on the screen, and so the issue, probably, lies in my query or the connection setup before it, I'm just not sure where.

```
<%-- 
Document   : content
Created on : May 6, 2015, 5:04:20 PM
Author     : Christopher
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@page import = "java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import = "java.util.logging.Level" %>
<%@page import = "java.util.logging.Logger" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>content</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <%!

public class Template {

public Template(){

    try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/itmd4515?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
        ,"itmd4515","itmd4515");
        PreparedStatement ppst = con.prepareStatement("select * from inventory where id = 3");
        ResultSet rs = ppst.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        String carModel = rs.getString("carModel");
        rs.close();
        con.close();

        System.out.println(carModel);

    }catch(SQLException ex){
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Template.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

}


    %>
    <br><br>
    <%= new java.util.Date() %>
</body>
```

[image: inventory]
The inventory table

I'm confident that the problem is somewhere in the above code, as there are no errors when I run the code; it simply doesn't display the car model.  Also, the database is properly configured and connected, so that likely isn't the issue either.

I apologize if the issue is an obvious one, I'm still getting a hang of JDBC and .jsp.  This is a maven web app done in Netbeans.

[image: logs]

The latest system messages

After modifying the code to output the SQLException and ClassNotFoundException as  I received the following output in my browser: com.mysql.jdbc.driver

Comment: You are printing to System.out (not to the web page). Did you check the server logs (where this hopefully ends up)?

Comment: You need to do some debugging. Put a break point  on the line where you create a connection and step through, checking values as you go to make sure everything is as you expect. Also, Java and HTML in the same file? That is not good practice. That page should just contain JSTL that display the data. The fetching of the data needs to be in a service class, in a separate file.

Comment: You should have put "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" in Class.forName. D of driver must be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

Your code declares Template class and constructor for this class. Why would it be executed if class is not even instantiated?

Apart from that this is a very weird way of writing JSP pages. You need to read some decent book about writing simple JSP pages: smth like "Core Servlets and Javaserver Pages: Core Technologies, Vol. 1 (2nd Edition)" - which is very old but give a clue to beginners where and how to write plain simple JSP/Servlets

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `System.out.println(carModel)` to`out.println(carModel)`

Have a test~

Here is a post for you [Why do we write out.println() in jsp instead of System.out.println()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396347/why-do-we-write-out-println-in-jsp-instead-of-system-out-println)

Comment: I tried, but then I receive an error "cannot find symbol
symbol: variable out
location: class SimplifiedJSPSServlet.Tempate" it might have something to do with using <%! %>, I'm still trying to work it out

Comment: @TechSavvySmurf

under your code  <h1>Welcome!</h1>,  replace the <%! to <%, remove the '!'

Comment: Done, but unfortunately still no output, not even an error

Comment: instantiate Template class: new Template();

Comment: or remove all these declarations: public class Template {

public Template(){

Comment: @TechSavvySmurf Yeah, you should new Template() as kachanov said.

Answer (score 0):

I never write class and method in jsp. If you wanna test the jdbc clause work or not, just write a simple java file, use a main method. Like below

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2014
 * Tanry Electronic Technology Co., Ltd.
 * ChangSha, China
 * 
 * All Rights Reserved.
 * 
 * First created on May 7, 2015 by liyzh
 * Last edited on May 7, 2015 by liyzh
 * 
 * 说明： TODO
 */
package com.tanry.business.module.lc.request;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/itmd4515?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "itmd4515", "itmd4515");
            PreparedStatement ppst = con.prepareStatement("select * from inventory where id = 3");
            ResultSet rs = ppst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String carModel = rs.getString("carModel");
                System.out.println(carModel);
            }
            rs.close();
            ppst.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            // Logger.getLogger(Template.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
            // null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Using an IDE like eclipse, you can debug your code really easily.

Comment: also: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver"); should be Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: @kachanov Success! That did it, thanks. If you could make that an official answer, I'll select it.

Comment: this cannot be official answer. the code you showed is as ugly as nuclear war. My suggestion just allowed you to see the result you wanted. Read the book I suggested