# jQuery function not working on window load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I've function which will invoked on page load and pass some value to another servlet using ajax. The problem is the jQuery function is not getting invoked on page load.

Here is my jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function($) {          
          //alert($.name);
            $.ajax({
             url:'ServiceToFetchDocType',
            data: {"name":repository},
             type:'post',
             cache:false,
             success: function(response)
             {
                //some code

             }
            });

        });
</script>
```

Here is the servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String entry=request.getParameter("name");
        System.out.println(entry);
    }
```

It is supposed to print the value of entry in console but nothing is coming up.

**EDIT:** It's not about just printing the value in console. The main question is the jquery function is not getting invoked on page load.

**EDIT 2:**
here is the repository

```
<script type="text/ajavscript">
        var repository = '${rep}';

        </script>
```

It is coming from another servlet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we write out.println() in jsp instead of System.out.println()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396347/why-do-we-write-out-println-in-jsp-instead-of-system-out-println)

Comment: @Andreas Nope..it's not just about print the value in servlet. I want to pass that value in servlet and perform some action. I wrote that sysout only to check if my servlet is able to receive the document. The question here is the query function is not getting invoked on page load.

Comment: any error in browser console?

Comment: No error..it just loads the jsp page. That's it !

Comment: what is `repository` here? also are you getting any alert? if you put any after page loads?

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan I've edited my question and no I'm not getting any alerts.

Comment: @Zeus07 you are not getting simple javascript alert? than dude check properly there must be some js issues on your webpage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146687/discussion-between-mahesh-singh-chouhan-and-zeus07).