# how to know whether php file handling the ajax request or not

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've this code snippet for `ajax` request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#temp').click(function() {
                var username = $('#un').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "inter.php",
                    data: 'user=' + username,
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if (! data.length === 0) {

                            $('#msg').append('available');
                            $('#sub').removeAttr('disabled');
                        } else {

                            $('#msg').append("Username not available");
                            $('#sub').attr('disabled', 'true');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and the code in **inter.php**

```
<?php

$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three');
if (in_array($_GET['user'], $arr)) {
    echo "Username available";
} else {
    //echo "0";
}
?>
```

But, every time I'm getting the message `Username not available`.
Can anybody help? I'm newbie to `ajax`.

**EDIT**
$_GET['user']
But the same problem remains.

Comment: You're passing data in `user`, while getting it by `$_GET['un']`.

Comment: how can i check whether my request is handled properly or not? I'd used `data.length === 0` in script to check. Is there any other method?

Comment: You can have `error` function same as success which get called if any error in ajax request call, but if you getting data or not the way you're doing seems fine. Btw where you've written `Username not available` ? We can't find in your posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug the code I'd added line:

```
alert(data + " " + data.length);
```

after

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
```

and found that I'm getting the proper message from my php file.
Then I found that the problem is with my handler

```
if(!data.length === 0){
```

where `!` operator is working on only `data.length` whether I need it to work on whole comparison.
I'd changed it to

```
if(!(data.length === 0)){
```

and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

The problem:

```
data: 'user=' + username,
$_GET['un']
```

You're not using the same parameter-name for "user name" or whatever. In the JS you're calling it "user", in PHP you're looking for "un".

Comment: You need to log & debug your AJAX and PHP, because there are several points the error could be occurring at -- and without information, you won't know.  Try putting in some `console.log()` to verify the AJAX response & some logging in your PHP.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323411/php-write-to-console

Comment: thanks for helping me out. The problem was with `if(!data.length === 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You're sending `?user=someName` but looking for `$_GET['un']`. Change it to `$_GET['user']`

Comment: I've changed `$_GET['user']` but still I'm getting `Username not available`

Comment: Are you sure that the username is correct? Trace the network traffic with Firebug. That will tell you what data is being sent to your server, and what the response is. That should help you debug things.