# Not able to access PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I am struggling/trying since last 24 hours with a simple thing, which i am not able to understand why i am not able to access the PHP variable. I know am doing something wrong and i have no idea what's that..

```
window.alert("Variable" + <?php  echo $_POST; ?> );
```

Its giving me output as `Function Array() {[native code]}`, How can i print the values ? and i think the POST attribute is blank, Can anyone check ? Why POST variable is blank ?

I am sending data to the file via POST method as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callAjaxAddition() {
    arguments0 = {
        arg1: $("#exampleForm input[id='pac-input']").val(),
        arg2: ("#exampleForm input[id='pac-input']").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processAjax.php",
        data: {
            arguments: arguments0
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#answer").html('<ul><li>' + data + '</li></ul>');
            send_apptn_req();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

and ProcessAjax.php file is

```
<?php $a=0;foreach($_POST['arguments'] as $v) $a= $v;echo $a;?>
```

Thanks in advance please..

Comment: You are missing a `$` when doing `arg2: ("#exampleForm input[id='pac-input']").val()`. It should be `$arg2: ("#exampleForm input[id='pac-input']").val()`

Answer (score 1):

> [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is an associative array of variables passed to the current
>   script.

**So you need to use `print_r` instead of `echo` .**

```
window.alert("Variable" + <?php  print_r($_POST); ?> );
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is an array so you should use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` instead of `echo`:

```
window.alert("Variable" + <?php  print_r($_POST); ?> );
```

If debugging the $_POST variable in Javascript is what you want to do I suggest you do this:

```
console.log(<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>);
```

And you'll see the content in your developer tools on your browser.

For reference you can look at the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323411/how-can-i-write-to-console-in-php).

**EDIT:**

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="first"/>
  <input type="text" name="second" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php if (isset($_POST)): ?>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    console.debug(<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>);
  </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT 2: (after you updated your code)**

Change the `type` option in the ajax jQuery function to `method` like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callAjaxAddition() {
    arguments0 = {
        arg1: $("#exampleForm input[id='pac-input']").val(),
        arg2: $("#exampleForm input[id='pac-input']").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "processAjax.php",
        data: {
            arguments: arguments0
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#answer").html('<ul><li>' + data + '</li></ul>');
            send_apptn_req();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Also note that after the AJAX POST, your `$_POST` variable will contain the `data` object that you passed to the `$.ajax` function and therefore what you are passing:

```
 data: {
   arguments: {
    arg1: $("#exampleForm input[id='pac-input']").val(),
    arg2: ("#exampleForm input[id='pac-input']").val()
   }
 }
```

will translate into:

```
Array (
  'arguments' => Array (
    'arg1': 'value of arg1'
    'arg2': 'value of arg2'
  )
)
```

So the loop in processAjax.php is quite useless since you're not looping through the inside array.

Comment: You should not have to echo a print, print (and print_r) already prints a string

Comment: @Jesse I totally agree, I'm going to edit to better reflect my intentions there (which was to have a visual representation of the $_POST)

Comment: @grim - Console Output - []  only and window.alert is blank .. It think the variables are not going to POST.. Can you check why ??

Comment: @grim - Still the variable is blank ...Please check the video, i have uploaded here the error http://tinypic.com/r/2di5405/8

Comment: @user2921939 what do you get if you do `console.log(arguments0);` right before calling `$.ajax`?

Comment: @user2921939 If `console.log(arguments0)` gives you `[]` then you are not properly fetching the values from the fields. Make sure that your jQuery selectors target the element you want `$("#exampleForm input[id='pac-input']")`. You are not providing your HTML so I cannot help you any further.