# In php, when will a inline <script> be resolved?

Tags: javascript, php, performance, debugging

I try to debug my slow php script submitting a query to several databases and several tables creating one resulting page.

In the php script I put in like this in the start:

```
echo '<script>console.log("Start ",Date.now());</script>';
```

taken from [How can I write to console in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323411/how-can-i-write-to-console-in-php)

And similar at the end of the php script.

But as it takes from 30s to 1 minute before I get the resulting page, the time difference from the start to end of the script printed in the firebug console is less than a second.

Like this:

Start 1460618023753

End   1460618023923

So I think I'm misunderstanding when these  inlines actually are run.

Can someone explain why this is so? And maybe suggest how I can, in principle, debug slow parts of my php code?

Comment: From the view point of php that is just a string, php does not execute that _at all_. That is javascript, it is executed on the client (if at all).

Comment: For debugging performance issues you can take a look at a profiler, maybe the one xdebug offers. It is not trivial to use, though. An easier to use alternative is phps `tick` feature: http://php.net/manual/de/function.register-tick-function.php You can use it to output a simple string like maybe a timestamp to some log file. That results in a list of steps taken. You should be able to spot what part of the code takes long like that.

Comment: php is compiled on the server first, and the javascript is not run until the html is output to the browser. that is why there is no time difference between your javascript. You need to get the times in php, ie. change `Date.now()` to php's [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) -> `echo '<script>console.log("Start ",'.time().');</script>';` as that will show when the php is executed.

Comment: ah, thanks arkascha and Sean. Now I understand the time I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To measure time in php you need to use php code.

At the begining run:

```
$start = time();
```

and at the end use

```
$duration = time() - $start;
echo '<script>console.log("Duration ",' . $duration . ');</script>';
```

You can also echo Start and End but you need to use php time:

```
echo '<script>console.log("Start ",' . time() . ');</script>';
```

and

```
echo '<script>console.log("End ",' . time() . ');</script>';
```