# how to log PHP to console in FF DevEd?

Tags: php, firefox, console.log

now that Firebug is throwing in the towel, does anyone know how to log PHP to the console in Firefox Developer Edition?  there is nothing on the Mozilla forum.  Firelogger/FirePHP obviously aren't going to work anymore.  i am hoping there is an equally elegant solution out there.  i'm not looking for something that requires me to write 15 lines of code to do something simple.

TIA.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323411/how-can-i-write-to-console-in-php

Comment: not elegant.  not simple.  not what i'm looking for.  but thanks anyway.  looking into Monolog...