# PHP print to terminal in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I type php code in visual studio code and I am looking to see if I can print the echo statements to the terminal when I run the debug.
I just stated with python and python will allow me to print to the terminal using print statements.
Will php let me do this? When I type php code and press debug, nothing happens. I already downloaded the php source files and set the environment variables for path.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323411/how-can-i-write-to-console-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use this plugin for the same. Its' called `PHP Debug`. The installation is mentioned there in the site itself.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug