# Vs Code debug variables characters limited to 1026

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to increase the character limit when viewing the variables while debugging? I can't view the entire string because it's very long.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is it a PHP file ?

Comment: yes it is php that i am debugging

Comment: Wow ok I thought for hours that my string was actually partial, that was very confusing. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this ref](https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug).

In `launch.json`:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        ...
        "xdebugSettings": {
            "max_data": 1500   //set a proper number.
        }
    }]
}
```

**Note**: Large `max_data` number may stuck IDE. Could print the variable in terminal using [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323411/how-can-i-write-to-the-console-in-php).