# Make a musical note

Tags: c#, javascript

Is there any way to make a musical note in C# / javascript? So you specify frequency, pitch, etc. and it plays something?

Comment: C# and Javascript don't come with speakers, unfortunately.  What platform are you building upon (ASP.NET, Winforms, etc?)

Comment: Probably a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep

Comment: Using Unity, attempting to make an audio kit as requested by someone. I'm guessing it was a joke, so I'll treat it like one.

Comment: @kirk...speaking of pedantic and unhelpful...

Comment: @kirk woll, I'm joking about the speakers, of course, but only because the question lacks context.  For example, the answer would be different if the OP is writing an ASP.NET MVC application and wants to hear a sound vs. a console application.  No offense intended.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C#, yes. JavaScript, not really (you could use Ajax and the HTML5 `<audio />` tag but that's not really a great idea).

In C#, you would do:

```
Console.Beep(frequencyInHertz, durationInMilliseconds);
```

. There are also various other ways to do about the same thing.