# Generating sound on the fly with javascript/html5

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

Is it possible to generate a constant sound stream with javascript/html5? For example, to generate a perpetual sine wave, I would have a callback function, that would be called whenever the output buffer is about to become empty:

```
function getSampleAt(timestep)
{
    return Math.sin(timestep);
}
```

(The idea is to use this to make an interactive synth. I don't know in advance how long a key will be pressed, so I can't use a fixed length buffer)

Comment: Since this question was asked a lot of things changed. If you are still interested I wrote an article on this here: http://marcgg.com/blog/2016/11/01/javascript-audio/

Comment: Try [Tone.js](https://tonejs.github.io/). A Web Audio framework for making interactive music in the browser. This library generates audio "on the fly" as you requested. Good luck!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### Using the HTML5 audio element

Cross-browser generative sustained audio using JavaScript and the `audio` element isn't currently possible, as Steven Wittens [notes in a blog post on creating a JavaScript synth:](http://acko.net/blog/javascript-audio-synthesis-with-html-5)

> "...there is no way to queue up chunks of synthesized audio for seamless playback".

#### Using the Web Audio API

The [Web Audio API](http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/specification/specification.html) was designed to facilitate JavaScript audio synthesis. The Mozilla Developer Network has a [Web Based Tone Generator](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API#Complete_Example:_Creating_a_Web_Based_Tone_Generator) that works in Firefox 4+ [[demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/c59yu/)]. Add these two lines to that code and you have a working synth with generative sustained audio upon keypress [[demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/HMwTT/) - works in Firefox 4 only, click the 'Results' area first, then press any key]:

```
window.onkeydown = start;  
window.onkeyup = stop;
```

The BBC's [page on the Web Audio API](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/researchanddevelopment/2010/11/mozilla-audio-data-api.shtml) is worth reviewing too. Unfortunately, support for the Web Audio API doesn't extend to other browsers yet.

#### Possible workarounds

To create a cross-browser synth at present, you'll likely have to fall back on prerecorded audio by:

1. Using long prerecorded ogg/mp3 sample tones, embedding them in separate `audio` elements and starting and stopping them upon keypress.
2. Embedding an swf file containing the audio elements and controlling playback via JavaScript. (This appears to be the method that the [Google Les Paul Doodle](http://www.google.com/logos/2011/lespaul.html) employs.)

Answer (score 65):

You can use the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) in most browsers now ([excepting IE and Opera Mini](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api)).

Try out this code:

```js
// one context per document
var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var osc = context.createOscillator(); // instantiate an oscillator
osc.type = 'sine'; // this is the default - also square, sawtooth, triangle
osc.frequency.value = 440; // Hz
osc.connect(context.destination); // connect it to the destination
osc.start(); // start the oscillator
osc.stop(context.currentTime + 2); // stop 2 seconds after the current time
```

If you want the volume lower, you can do something like this:

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext();
var osc = context.createOscillator();
var vol = context.createGain();

vol.gain.value = 0.1; // from 0 to 1, 1 full volume, 0 is muted
osc.connect(vol); // connect osc to vol
vol.connect(context.destination); // connect vol to context destination
osc.start(context.currentTime + 3); // start it three seconds from now
```

I got most of this from experimenting in chromium while reading the [Web Audio API Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/), which I found from @brainjam 's link.

Lastly, it is very helpful to inspect the various objects in the chrome inspector (ctrl-shift-i).

Comment: How can I start again after I stopped it? It says Failed to execute 'start' on 'AudioScheduledSourceNode': cannot call start more than once.

Is there alternative functions to use in case I want to start and stop depending on certain consition? resume() and suspend() doesn't seem to work

Comment: @devN this is by design. You can, however, create a function that creates new nodes each time.

Answer (score 19):

Sure! You could use the tone synthesizer in this demo:

[image]

```js
audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

show();

function show() {
  frequency = document.getElementById("fIn").value;
  document.getElementById("fOut").innerHTML = frequency + ' Hz';

  switch (document.getElementById("tIn").value * 1) {
    case 0: type = 'sine'; break;
    case 1: type = 'square'; break;
    case 2: type = 'sawtooth'; break;
    case 3: type = 'triangle'; break;
  }
  document.getElementById("tOut").innerHTML = type;

  volume = document.getElementById("vIn").value / 100;
  document.getElementById("vOut").innerHTML = volume;

  duration = document.getElementById("dIn").value;
  document.getElementById("dOut").innerHTML = duration + ' ms';
}

function beep() {
  var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
  var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();

  oscillator.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

  gainNode.gain.value = volume;
  oscillator.frequency.value = frequency;
  oscillator.type = type;

  oscillator.start();

  setTimeout(
    function() {
      oscillator.stop();
    },
    duration
  );
};
```

```html
frequency
<input type="range" id="fIn" min="40" max="6000" oninput="show()" />
<span id="fOut"></span><br>
type
<input type="range" id="tIn" min="0" max="3" oninput="show()" />
<span id="tOut"></span><br>
volume
<input type="range" id="vIn" min="0" max="100" oninput="show()" />
<span id="vOut"></span><br>
duration
<input type="range" id="dIn" min="1" max="5000" oninput="show()" />
<span id="dOut"></span>
<br>
<button onclick='beep();'>Play</button>
```

Have fun!

I got the solution from Houshalter here:
[How do I make Javascript beep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep)

You can clone and tweak the code here:
[Tone synthesizer demo on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/tupoyi/4/edit?html,js,outputhttp://)

### Compatible browsers:

- Chrome mobile & desktop
- Firefox mobile & desktop Opera mobile, mini & desktop
- Android browser
- Microsoft Edge browser
- Safari on iPhone or iPad

### Not Compatible

- Internet Explorer version 11 (but does work on the Edge browser)

Answer (score 11):

Web Audio API is coming to Chrome.  See http://googlechrome.github.io/web-audio-samples/samples/audio/index.html

Follow the directions in "Getting Started" there, and then check out the very impressive demos.

**Update(2017):** by now this is a much more mature interface.  The API is documented at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API

Answer (score 3):

You can generate wav-e file in the fly and play it ([src](https://gist.github.com/literallylara/7ece1983fab47365108c47119afb51c7))

```js
// Legend
// DUR - duration in seconds   SPS - sample per second (default 44100)
// NCH - number of channels    BPS - bytes per sample

// t - is number from range [0, DUR), return number in range [0, 1]
function getSampleAt(t,DUR,SPS)
{
    return Math.sin(6000*t); 
}

function genWAVUrl(fun, DUR=1, NCH=1, SPS=44100, BPS=1) {
  let size = DUR*NCH*SPS*BPS; 
  let put = (n,l=4) => [(n<<24),(n<<16),(n<<8),n].filter((x,i)=>i<l).map(x=> String.fromCharCode(x>>>24)).join('');
  let p = (...a) => a.map( b=> put(...[b].flat()) ).join(''); 
  let data = `RIFF${put(44+size)}WAVEfmt ${p(16,[1,2],[NCH,2],SPS,NCH*BPS*SPS,[NCH*BPS,2],[BPS*8,2])}data${put(size)}`
  
  for (let i = 0; i < DUR*SPS; i++) {
    let f= Math.min(Math.max(fun(i/SPS,DUR,SPS),0),1);
    data += put(Math.floor( f * (2**(BPS*8)-1)), BPS);
  }
  
  return "data:Audio/WAV;base64," + btoa(data);
}


var WAV = new Audio( genWAVUrl(getSampleAt,5) ); // 5s
WAV.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
document.body.appendChild(WAV);
//WAV.play()
```

Here is visualistation

```js
function getSampleAt(t,DUR,SPS)
{
    return 0.5+Math.sin(15*t)/(1+t*t); 
}


// ----------------------------------------------

function genWAVUrl(fun, DUR=1, NCH=1, SPS=44100, BPS=1) {
  let size = DUR*NCH*SPS*BPS; 
  let put = (n,l=4) => [(n<<24),(n<<16),(n<<8),n].filter((x,i)=>i<l).map(x=> String.fromCharCode(x>>>24)).join('');
  let p = (...a) => a.map( b=> put(...[b].flat()) ).join(''); 
  let data = `RIFF${put(44+size)}WAVEfmt ${p(16,[1,2],[NCH,2],SPS,NCH*BPS*SPS,[NCH*BPS,2],[BPS*8,2])}data${put(size)}`
  
  for (let i = 0; i < DUR*SPS; i++) {
    let f= Math.min(Math.max(fun(i/SPS,DUR,SPS),0),1);
    data += put(Math.floor( f * (2**(BPS*8)-1)), BPS);
  }
  
  return "data:Audio/WAV;base64," + btoa(data);
}

function draw(fun, DUR=1, NCH=1, SPS=44100, BPS=1) {
  time.innerHTML=DUR+'s';
  time.setAttribute('x',DUR-0.3);
  svgCh.setAttribute('viewBox',`0 0 ${DUR} 1`);
  let p='', n=100; // n how many points to ommit
  for (let i = 0; i < DUR*SPS/n; i++) p+= ` ${DUR*(n*i/SPS)/DUR}, ${1-fun(n*i/SPS, DUR,SPS)}`;
  chart.setAttribute('points', p);
}

function frame() {
  let t=WAV.currentTime;
  point.setAttribute('cx',t)
  point.setAttribute('cy',1-getSampleAt(t))
  window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}

function changeStart(e) {
  var r = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = e.clientX - r.left;
  WAV.currentTime = dur*x/r.width;
  WAV.play()
}

var dur=5; // seconds 
var WAV = new Audio(genWAVUrl(getSampleAt,dur));
draw(getSampleAt,dur);
frame();
```

```css
.chart { border: 1px dashed #ccc; }
.axis { font-size: 0.2px}
audio { outline: none; }
```

```html
Click at blue line (make volume to max):
<svg class="chart" id="svgCh" onclick="changeStart(event)">    
  <circle cx="0" cy="-1" r="0.05" style="fill: rgba(255,0,0,1)" id="point"></circle>
  <polyline id="chart" fill="none" stroke="#0074d9" stroke-width="0.01" points=""/>
  <text x="0.03" y="0.9" class="axis">0</text>
  <text x="0.03" y="0.2" class="axis">1</text>
  <text x="4.8" y="0.9" class="axis" id="time"></text>
</svg><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not real answer on your question because you have asked for a JavaScript solution, but you can use ActionScript. It should run on all major browsers.

- [ActionScript API Audio Generation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WSE523B839-C626-4983-B9C0-07CF1A087ED7.html)

You can call ActionScript functions from within JavaScript.

- [ActionScript API Call JavaScript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb1.html)

In that way you can wrap the ActionScript sound generation functions and make a JavaScript implementation of them. Just use Adobe Flex to build a tiny swf and then use that as backend for your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have looked for like forever and in the end I managed to do it myself like I wanted. Maybe you will like it too.
Simple slider with frequency and push on/off:

```js
buttonClickResult = function () {
 var button = document.getElementById('btn1');

 button.onclick = function buttonClicked()  {

  if(button.className=="off")  {
   button.className="on";
   oscOn ();
  }

  else if(button.className=="on")  {
   button.className="off";
   oscillator.disconnect();
  }
 }
};

buttonClickResult();

var oscOn = function(){

 window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
 var context = new AudioContext();
 var gainNode = context.createGain ? context.createGain() : context.createGainNode();

 //context = new window.AudioContext();
 oscillator = context.createOscillator(),
   oscillator.type ='sine';

 oscillator.frequency.value = document.getElementById("fIn").value;
 //gainNode = createGainNode();
 oscillator.connect(gainNode);
 gainNode.connect(context.destination);
 gainNode.gain.value = 1;
 oscillator.start(0);
};
```

```html
<p class="texts">Frekvence [Hz]</p>
<input type="range" id="fIn" min="20" max="20000" step="100" value="1234" oninput="show()" />
<span id="fOut"></span><br>
<input class="off" type="button" id="btn1" value="Start / Stop" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to generate sounds and try different frequencies to generate even more sounds:

```
    // generate sounds using frequencies
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = "triangle"; // "square" "sine" "sawtooth"
oscillator.frequency.value = frequency; // 440 is default (try different frequencies)
oscillator.connect(audioContext.destination); // connects to your audio output
oscillator.start(0); // immediately starts when triggered
oscillator.stop(0.5); // stops after 0.5 seconds
```