# How to generate a simple continuous tone in the browser using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, audio, web, browser

Goal: In the browser. User presses mouse button -> A continuous tone plays -> User releases mouse button -> The tone stops.

I can handle the mouse press event, it's the audio part I'm having a difficult time with.

I have looked at the Web Audio API and I can't make heads or tails of it. I can't seem to find a simple user friendly library, piece of code or guide to achieve my goal. There's gotta be some way to do this that doesn't involve me first getting a sound engineering degree. Ideally I'm looking for a library that has code like this:

```
function playTone(frequencyHz) {
  let myGDamnTone = sound engineering mumbo jumbo * frequencyHz;
  ...
  return myGDamnTone;
}
```

Where I can then simply go:

```
playTone(441);
```

If there isn't any such solution out there, I'd like the next best thing. I'm looking for the simplest solution to achieve this goal and by simplest I mean the one that will require as few parameter inputs and lines of code from me as possible.

Comment: Have you seen this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343450/generating-sound-on-the-fly-with-javascript-html5

Comment: esp. [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16573282/989121) is pretty straight-forward.

Comment: I hadn't seen that one and it is perfect! Thanks for the help.