# Are there browser integrated notifications sound(beep, click, etc), that one can play in html?

Tags: javascript, html, notifications, playsound, integrated

Are there integrated sounds into the browser(Chrome, Edge, FF, etc), just as they are for fonts, that one can use to play notification sounds, such as beeps and so on??

Not something as
https://base64.guru/developers/html/audio
or
[How to play a notification sound on websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105063/how-to-play-a-notification-sound-on-websites)

```
function playSound(url) {
  const audio = new Audio(url);
  audio.play();
}
<button onclick="playSound('https://your-file.mp3');">Play</button>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating sound on the fly with javascript/html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343450/generating-sound-on-the-fly-with-javascript-html5)

Comment: Interresting concept, but except if you are a sound engineer you know what to play for a beep and alarm, etc.
One has integrated fonts, system icons(e.g. mouse pointer), systems sound, so I'm wondering if they are no integrated notifications into browser that one has access to.

Comment: No, not really. You can use a library with already generated sounds

Comment: Maybe I wrongly interpreted, would you be so kind to shed light and give a few example, for instance a notification sound when a task is completed. Thx