# Play a beep when a countdown reaches 0

Tags: javascript, audio, timer, countdown, beep

Im trying to create a simple countdown timer that plays a beep when it's done. My countdown timer is working. My sound file has been created and is in place. The script to play the sound file is not working, and thats what Im asking for help with.

Ive looked around for answers, and most recommend hooking up to an external JS library, which I do not want to do. That being said, here is my code:

```
<script language="Javascript">

var countdown;
var countdown_number;

var audio = new Audio('audio/beep.mp3'); 


function countdown_init() {
    countdown_number = 11;
    countdown_trigger();
}

function countdown_trigger() {
    if(countdown_number > 0) {
        countdown_number--;
        document.getElementById('countdown_text').innerHTML = countdown_number;
        if(countdown_number > 0) {
            countdown = setTimeout('countdown_trigger()', 1000);

if(countdown_number === 0) { audio.play(); }

        }

    }
}

function countdown_clear() {
    clearTimeout(countdown);
}





</script>





<div>
    <input type="button" value="start countdown" onClick="countdown_init()" />
    <input type="button" value="stop countdown" onClick="countdown_clear()" /> <br /><br />
</div>
<div id="countdown_text">Placeholding text</div>
```

Comment: `var audio = new Audio('/audio/beep.mp3'); audio.play()`

Comment: I like yours better than mine, its simpler. But, this is playing as soon as the page loads now. I tried putting the "audio.play()" into the countdown === 0 section, but that didnt work.

Comment: @adeneo: would that work if the track takes a while to load?

Comment: Thank you! This coupled with the extra help I got below and it worked perfectly!

Comment: You should be cautious about using a string as the first argument to setTimeout(), as this actually becomes an eval() statement - which is evil.  Additionally, all of your functions and variables are in the global scope - which is also evil.  Finally, use of the -- operator should be avoided when possible.  I'd recommend using a linter such as [JSHint](http://jshint.com/)

Comment: Im an newbie with javascript, trying to teach myself. I dont really understand what anything you just said means.

Comment: @wolfgangpwnz notice in the `setTimeout` functions you have `setTimeout('countdown_trigger()')` but in the answers below people have used `setTimeout(countdown_trigger)` This is because the setTimeout method can take a function (without brackets) and it will execute it. This is the preferred approach. If you pass a string (wrapped in quotes `''`) then the timeout method will try to `eval` the function which means searching for functions with the same name and executing it. This is bad :)

Comment: Ohhh. I changed that around and pasted it into JSHint and it said there werent anymore errors. And it still works. Thanks! Im always willing to learn new stuff about syntax, because thats the part I cant really learn by myself without a class, and my college totally skimmed over javascript when teaching us. So Ive been on my own lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your sound manager was that you needed to call createSound *after* the `onready` event:

```
 var countdown;
var countdown_number;
var mySoundObject;

function countdown_trigger() {
    if (countdown_number > 0) {
        countdown_number--;
        document.getElementById('countdown_text').innerHTML = countdown_number;
        if (countdown_number > 0) {
            countdown = setTimeout(countdown_trigger, 1000);
        }

        if (countdown_number === 0) {
            mySoundObject.play();
        }
    }
}

function countdown_clear() {
    clearTimeout(countdown);
}

function countdown_init() {
    countdown_number = 11;
    countdown_trigger();
}

document.getElementById('start').onclick = countdown_init;
document.getElementById('stop').onclick = countdown_clear;

soundManager.setup({
    url: 'http://ivdemo.chaseits.co.uk/SoundManager2-2.97a.20131201/swf/soundmanager2_flash_xdomain/soundmanager2_flash9_debug.swf',
    flashVersion: 9,
    useHTML5Audio: true,
    html5Test: 'maybe',
    preferFlash: false,
    onready: function () {
        mySoundObject = soundManager.createSound({
            id: 'mySound',
            url: 'http://www.freshly-ground.com/misc/music/20060826%20-%20Armstrong.mp3'
        });
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle Demo http://jsfiddle.net/TBS8C/16/**

**EDIT**

It looks like you changed your question to not using soundManager anymore. Here's a demo with HTML5 audio only.

```js
var countdown;
var countdown_number;
var audio = new Audio('http://www.freshly-ground.com/misc/music/20060826%20-%20Armstrong.mp3');

function countdown_trigger() {
    if (countdown_number > 0) {
        countdown_number--;
        document.getElementById('countdown_text').innerHTML = countdown_number;
        if (countdown_number > 0) {
            countdown = setTimeout(countdown_trigger, 1000);
        }

        if (countdown_number === 0) {
            audio.play()
        }
    }
}

function countdown_clear() {
    clearTimeout(countdown);
}

function countdown_init() {
    countdown_number = 11;
    countdown_trigger();
}

document.getElementById('start').onclick = countdown_init;
document.getElementById('stop').onclick = countdown_clear;
```

```html
<input type="button" value="start countdown" id="start" />
<input type="button" value="stop countdown" id="stop" />
<div id="countdown_text"></div>
```

**JSFiddle Demo http://jsfiddle.net/nsmp8mfv/1/**

Comment: I changed the fiddle url earlier make sure it's http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/TBS8C/16/

Comment: Well, that is weird. i copied and pasted your code into mine, not changing a thing, and it didnt work. but it works in the demo

Comment: YES! The last one worked! My problem always tends to be syntax. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
soundManager.getSoundById("mySound").play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaner solution using pure javascript with the HTML5 Audio element.

```js
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global window */

(function () {

    'use strict';

    var _count = 10,
        _countdownTimer;
    
    function resetCounter() {
        if (_countdownTimer) {
            window.clearInterval(_countdownTimer);
        }
        _countdownTimer = null;
        _count = 10;
        document.getElementById("countdownDiv").innerText = "";
    }
  
    function startCountdown() {
              
        if (!_countdownTimer) {
          
            _countdownTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
              
                document.getElementById("countdownDiv").innerText = _count;
                _count = _count - 1;
                
                if (_count < 0) {
                    resetCounter();                  
                    document.getElementById("countdownDiv").innerText = "Beep";
                    document.getElementById("beepAudio").play();
                }
                
            }, 1000); 
          
        }
    }

    function stopCountdown() {
        resetCounter();
    }
  
    
    // Init
    document.getElementById("beepAudio").src = "http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1252&type=mp3";
    document.getElementById("beepAudio").load();
    
    document.getElementById("startButton").onclick = startCountdown;
    document.getElementById("stopButton").onclick = stopCountdown;
    
}());
```

```html
<audio id="beepAudio"></audio>
<div>
    <input id="startButton" type="button" value="Start" />
    <input id="stopButton" type="button" value="Stop" />
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
<div id="countdownDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tone synthesizer in this demo:

[image]

```js
audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

show();

function show() {
  frequency = document.getElementById("fIn").value;
  document.getElementById("fOut").innerHTML = frequency + ' Hz';

  switch (document.getElementById("tIn").value * 1) {
    case 0: type = 'sine'; break;
    case 1: type = 'square'; break;
    case 2: type = 'sawtooth'; break;
    case 3: type = 'triangle'; break;
  }
  document.getElementById("tOut").innerHTML = type;

  volume = document.getElementById("vIn").value / 100;
  document.getElementById("vOut").innerHTML = volume;

  duration = document.getElementById("dIn").value;
  document.getElementById("dOut").innerHTML = duration + ' ms';
}

function beep() {
  var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
  var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();

  oscillator.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

  gainNode.gain.value = volume;
  oscillator.frequency.value = frequency;
  oscillator.type = type;

  oscillator.start();

  setTimeout(
    function() {
      oscillator.stop();
    },
    duration
  );
};
```

```html
frequency
<input type="range" id="fIn" min="40" max="6000" oninput="show()" />
<span id="fOut"></span><br>
type
<input type="range" id="tIn" min="0" max="3" oninput="show()" />
<span id="tOut"></span><br>
volume
<input type="range" id="vIn" min="0" max="100" oninput="show()" />
<span id="vOut"></span><br>
duration
<input type="range" id="dIn" min="1" max="5000" oninput="show()" />
<span id="dOut"></span>
<br>
<button onclick='beep();'>Play</button>
```

Have fun!

I got the solution from Houshalter here:
[How do I make Javascript beep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep)

You can clone and tweak the code here:
[Tone synthesizer demo on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/tupoyi/4/edit?html,js,outputhttp://)

### Compatible browsers:

- Chrome mobile & desktop
- Firefox mobile & desktop Opera mobile, mini & desktop
- Android browser
- Microsoft Edge browser
- Safari on iPhone or iPad

### Not Compatible

- Internet Explorer version 11 (but does work on the Edge browser)