# Play a beep sound on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, embed

OK I've read several answers here but they didn't help me at all (in fact, none of them is being accepted as answer)

Question is how to **"Play a beep sound"** on **"button click"**

I am trying to make a website that works on touchscreen device so I want every button click events will play a beep sound, that should be nicer for users who using the website. Beep sound file is here: http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav . I only need this work on Google Chrome (supports HTML5)

I understand this need to work on client-side so I tried this:

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function PlaySound(soundObj) {
        var sound = document.getElementById(soundObj);
        sound.Play();
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<embed src="/beep.wav" autostart="false" type="audio/mpeg" loop="false" width="0" height="0" id="beep" enablejavascript="true" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnExit" runat="server" OnClick="lbtnExit_Click" OnClientClick="PlaySound('beep')" CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-danger" Text="Exit <i class='fa fa-sign-out' style='font-size: 40px'></i>"></asp:LinkButton>
```

But it doesn't work, nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: Try using an `<audio>` tag: http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/audio.html

Comment: Try this one i think it's useful for you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You could use an audio tag like this:

```
    <audio id="audio" src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav" autoplay="false" ></audio>
    <a onclick="playSound();"> Play</a>
    <script>
    function playSound() {
          var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
          sound.play();
      }
    </script>
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/S9Ipogq4M2fqWVKPvvEh?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. For Internet Explorer 10 use .mp3 instead of .wav

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) _autostart_ is not an `audio` attribute. Instead it should be _autoplay_.

Comment: autoplay="false" is not respected by Firefox 86. Should remove the attribute for it to NOT autoplay. The same happens with the attribute loop.

Answer (score 16):

Admitting you already have something like `<div id='btn'>Click to play!</div>` in your html, you could do it as simple as:

```js
$('#btn').click( () => new Audio('mp3/audio.mp3').play() );
```

This is the best solution IMO because it allow to click multiple times quickly on the button without problem (which is not possible in other answers at the time) and is a one liner.

```js
const audioUrl = 'https://freewavesamples.com/files/Ensoniq-ESQ-1-Piano-C3.wav'

$('.btn').click( () => new Audio(audioUrl).play() ); // that will do the trick !!
```

```css
body {padding: 16px;}

.btn {
  background: tomato;
  padding:15px;
  border-radius:5px;
  color:#fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.15) inset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class='btn'>Click to play!</span>
```

[Example on codepen](https://codepen.io/seb-rom-o/pen/EOMGXa?editors=1010#0)

Answer (score 13):

This works fine

```js
function playSound () {
    document.getElementById('play').play();
}
```

```html
<audio id="play" src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav"></audio>

<button onclick="playSound()">Play</button>
```

Answer (score 12):

Technically, the following doesn't answer the question about "playing" a beep, but if asking how to "generate" a beep, then consider the following code that I found on [this website](https://odino.org/emit-a-beeping-sound-with-javascript/):

```
a=new AudioContext();
function beep(vol, freq, duration){
  v=a.createOscillator();
  u=a.createGain();
  v.connect(u);
  v.frequency.value=freq;
  v.type="square";
  u.connect(a.destination);
  u.gain.value=vol*0.01;
  v.start(a.currentTime);
  v.stop(a.currentTime+duration*0.001);
}
```

Sample values for the call: `beep(20, 100, 30)`. The aforementioned website includes more details and sound samples.

The sound can be in response to a button click or programmatically generated at will. I have used it in Chrome but have not tried it in other browsers.

Comment: That's really neat. Run a few calls in parallel and you can get some nice chords going.

Answer (score 8):

With raw JavaScript, you can simply call:

```
new Audio('sound.wav').play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Been driving me crazy, but with JQuery I found a solution... not really the best way to do it, but it worked properly for me...

```
function ding() {
      $("body").append('<embed src="/ding.mp3" autostart=false autoplay=false type="audio/mpeg" loop="false" width="0" height="0" id="beep" enablejavascript="true" />');
      setTimeout(function(){ $("#beep").remove(); },2000);
}
```

not sure how much of the embed tag is really required, but once it started working, I stopped writing (embed copied from another solution).

Hope this helps someone else (or helps me the next time I forget)

Comment: Urgh, this is clumsy. Why not using `function ding() { new Audio('/ding.mp3').play(); }` ?

Answer (score 0):

expanding on Alan M.'s answer, this will prevent console errors if unable to run due to no user event yet

```
var actx = false;
function beep(vol, freq, duration){
    try{
        if(!actx) actx = new AudioContext();
        v=actx.createOscillator();
        u=actx.createGain();
        v.connect(u);
        v.frequency.value=freq;
        u.connect(actx.destination);
        u.gain.value=vol*0.01;
        v.start(actx.currentTime);
        v.stop(actx.currentTime+duration*0.001);
    }catch{
        // ignore
    }
}
```