# How to make sound when a <a> or <button> is clicked in JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

How can I make a sound ("MySound.mp3") hidden in the background when a `<a>` element or `<button>` element with the id "click_sound" is clicked in JavaScript, is it possible?

Remember I want to make a sound in the background if an `<a>` or `<button>` are clicked!

The Code:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <a id="click_sound">Click me</a>
  <button id="click_sound">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

The sound file name:
MySound.mp3

Comment: google "html5 audio element/tag"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play a beep sound on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567580/play-a-beep-sound-on-button-click)

Comment: yes I am familiar with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you are asking is to play the audio using javascript, when the `button` or `a` (or really any) tag is clicked. There are a few ways you could do this:

You could run the javascript in an `onmouseup` element:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <a id="click_sound" onmouseup="new Audio('path_to_audio_file.mp3').play()">Click me</a>
    <button id="click_sound" onmouseup="new Audio('path_to_audio_file.mp3').play()">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

or better yet, not run the audio constructor every time:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <a id="click_sound" onmouseup="audio.play()">Click me</a>
    <button id="click_sound" onmouseup="audio.play()">Click me</button>

      <script>const audio = new Audio('path_to_audio_file.mp3')</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to use an external script (either because you have other javascript, or you just prefer it that way, which I personally do) simply put it on the `window` object:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <a id="click_sound" onmouseup="window.audio.play()">Click me</a>
    <button id="click_sound" onmouseup="window.audio.play()">Click me</button>

      <script src='./path_to_file/somefile.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

somefile.js:

```js
  window.audio = new Audio('./path_to_audio/sound.mp3')
```

Please let me know if you need any more information about any of the above.

**Note:**
You could also use:

```js
document.getElementById('click_sound').addEventListener('mouseup', () =>  new Audio('path_to_audio_file.mp3').play())
```

To achieve the same thing.

For more information refer to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseup.asp) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) or look up "javascript 'Audio' constructor" and "onmouseup event".