# JS for Greasemonkey to define block

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, greasemonkey

I need help in creating script to define a block DIV .

There is a service in which you sound signal with the appearance of this side

```
<div class="captcha-flow-row" onmouseout="Anti.dashboard.flowActive = 1;"
     onmouseover="Anti.dashboard.flowActive = 0;" style="">
```

in the tree of elements this block is always hidden by style="display:none;"

And still need to make a timer to check every 2 seconds ...

P.S. condition of the item before and after the start of the process:

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: Question is not very clear

Comment: <div class="captcha-flow-row" onmouseout="Anti.dashboard.flowActive = 1;" onmouseover="Anti.dashboard.flowActive = 0;" style="">   I need to track the emergence of this block on the screen

Comment: Not enough information. Does the GreaseMonkey script create this div, or does it have to check, every 2 seconds, if this div now exists? Also, you seem to have two questions: how to build the script, and why is the div hidden.

Comment: need sound your horn when this div appears on the page. It would mean that the process of solving the captcha started.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqaa6j16wkweywb/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202015-10-02%2013.06.19.png?dl=0         https://www.dropbox.com/s/acq81fmz9p69oqw/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202015-10-02%2013.07.36.png?dl=0

Comment: above two screenshot showing the condition of the item before andafter the start of the process ... That's got to catch the beginning of the process of solving and sound the horn

Answer (score -1):

Instead of timers it's possible to detect the change *right when it occurs* using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Detect DIV
// @include       http://somesite/somepath*
// ==/UserScript==

var div = document.querySelector("#captcha_dashboard div.captcha-flow-row");
var ob = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    if (div.style.display != "none") {
        alert('DIV IS VISIBLE');
        ob.disconnect(); // stop monitoring the page
    }
});
ob.observe(div, {attributes: true, attributeFilter: ["style"]});
```

As for audio beep, it's a complicated task, see [the solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep).

Comment: Updated the code in accordance with the posted screenshots.