# Send an alert from an open page to another (php, javascript, html)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, alert

I am developing a website that  has a receptionist page   and a user page with multiple user logins. The logged in users are displayed in a table at the receptionist page and one of the columns of the table is the status of the user ( ready or busy). The table is refreshed using ajax every 5 seconds to prevent the web page from refreshing. Each user can log in ( with thier own page) and change their status( ready to busy or busy to ready).

The table is stored in a sql database.

The user page has the option to change the  state of the logged in user from ready to busy ( or vice verse)  with a drop down menu and a submit button. What i need is to also send and alert or sound to the receptionist page whenever any user switches to the ready state.

I have looked all over the internet but none of the answers have worked for me.

Thanks for your replies. I  understand that I could use ajax to query the database to see if a user is ready, however that will cause it to make a  notification every time it checks. What i need is for the receptionist to be notified only 1 time each time that a user sets status to ready.  I was thinking of making another table that  gets updated every time a user  changes their status to ready and time stamp it. So that  if there is a change in the time stamp it means that some one  newly updated it so the signal should be sent.

I made the table and made a php page that returns a string with the time stamp of the table  but i dont know how to use the returned string in java script.

Comment: Check this link may be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep

Comment: You don't need communication between tabs,just use ajax to check that value in table ,nothing special.If you do like this you can also check if player logged off

Comment: thanks for your reply. I  understand that i could use ajax to query the database to see if a user is ready, however that will cause it to make a  notification every time it checks. What i need s for the receptionist to be notified only 1 time each time that a user sets status to ready.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.   I  made an SQL table with a time stamp, whenever any user sets their status to ready the time stamp gets updated. I made a java script that  reads the time stamp every few seconds. If the time stamp is different than the initial time stamp then a sound is played.

Answer (score -1):

@O.Rases gave you the best solution.I did something like this in past using ajax and php. 
A solution can be the following.
1  Every 10s, sent a Ajax call to the server.

2 In the server, using php, you can **select** users that changed their status in the last 11s (**+1s** for time-consuming script in the server).

3 after selection is done, sent the user back to the receptionist page.
hope it helps