# How to check consol.log and play sound in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am planning for queue system application using WebSocket ,PHP ,MySQL ,HTML to send console.log from one client to another to play sound for next queue ,
now I want to check in clinet2 if console.log value which I receive it client ='Hello From Client1!' paly sound or if = 'another message' do action.

```js
    Client1
    <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send Msg</button>
</body>
<script>
    // Create WebSocket connection.
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');

    // Connection opened
    socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
        console.log('Connected to WS Server')
    });

    // Listen for messages
    socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
    });

    const sendMessage = () => {
        socket.send('Hello From Client1!');
    }
</script>
```

```js
    Client2
    <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send Msg</button>
</body>
<script>
    // Create WebSocket connection.
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');

    // Connection opened
    socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
        console.log('Connected to WS Server')
    });

    // Listen for messages
    socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
    });

    const sendMessage = () => {
        socket.send('Hello From Client2!');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you try to access console.log instead of just the data that you need?

Comment: `console.log` isn't exactly a means of choice for storing and reading data. Have your data in variables instead of trying to operate on console dumps.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep.

Comment: Thanks but playing sound is not a big issue, the issue I is how to read data come in console. Log

Comment: Have your data in variables instead of trying to operate on console dumps. – 
Markus AO
 can you send me example please,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All,

I think I got some code can help me.
I add in Client 1

```js
<script>
var connection = new WebSocket ('ws://localhost:3000');
connection.onmessage = function (event){
document.getElementById("sul").value=event.data;
};
    const sendMessage = () => {
        socket.send("test");

    }
</script>
```

```html
<output type="text" id="sul" value="" readonly></output>
```

and client 2

```js
    socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
        if (event.data =='sul 1'){
         console.log('Here i can put my play sound');
         playsound();
        }
    });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).