# Cross-platform, cross-browser way to play sound using jQuery 1.4?

Tags: jquery, audio

I'm trying to get jQuery to play a sound on element hover/click. (It's like a flash website without flash)

I've tried the methods recommended in [Cross-platform, cross-browser way to play sound from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript), the jQuery Sound plugin and a couple of other tutorials without any success. I'm assuming this is because they haven't been updated since 2008.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: You can find the jQuery sound plug in at http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/plugins/sound/jquery.sound.js

Comment: Could you use this jQuery sound plugin (http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/)?

Comment: I glanced at it, but thought that it was a bit too heavy for what I wanted. I'll give it a second look. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/ ? You could try inserting its play command in a jquery hover function

Comment: try: jQuery('#resource_audio').attr("src",srclink)[0].play(); found from: http://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Don't need any of those. The HTML  tag, combined with JavaScript, will do the trick.

```
<audio id="soundHandle" style="display: none;"></audio>
<script>
  soundHandle = document.getElementById('soundHandle');
  soundHandle.src = '/blah/blah.mp3';
  soundHandle.play();
</script>
```

Comment: That's a short bit of code. I'm more comfortable with jQuery, but how would I use java to attach this to a mouse over event?

Comment: @Erin: Javascript != Java, and this is pure Javascript. Note, however, that this is not cross-browser at all as it uses the HTML5 `<audio>` element (not working on IE at all, different browsers supporting different formats/codecs, etc.). See: http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This **should** be the way to go. Yes, it's not cross-browser (yet), but it will be pretty soon and **it is the standard**. Actually, the only browser **not** currently supporting it is Internet Explorer. Source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio

Comment: No, there are more browsers that do not support it, especially in the mobile sector. Plus the question emphasizes cross-browser and cross-platform compatibility. When the solution works for less then 50% of the market it doesn't satisfy this requirement.

Comment: And you think more mobile devices support Flash than `<audio>`? I doubt that's true, and even if it is, the relevant devices (that is, current smartphones -- iPhone, Android) support it. So, percentage-wise, I think more mobile devices support `<audio>` than Flash. Even if I'm wrong (if you have figures please correct me), I will be right in the near future. Also, that "less than 50%" is about to change pretty soon, too (IE is down to 60% from 95% a few years ago). If you want to be future-proof, use `<audio>`.

Comment: No but IE does not support it. iPhones do support the tag, but not in a reasonably scriptable manner (they will play the sound on a dedicated screen) thus again useless for this purpose. The truth is that sound (as in a user-interface element, not playing an mp3 song) is currently out of today's cross-browser compatible techniques. Also the percentage doesn't have to be 50% to not be cross-browser compliant, you should be aiming for something like 5%.

Comment: Please note that this uses only one channel, which means that one sound can be played at the same time. See http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/audio.html for a multichannel version

Comment: I don't know why, when I was trying to implement this, I could not get this to work till I added `soundHandle.load();` What's missing?

Comment: I had to use an .ogg file to get it to play on firefox

Answer (score 6):

Actually it's impossible to do in a truly cross-browser compliant way as for example iPhones will play sound only on a dedicated player "page". However some of the plugins in the other answers should do the job for most (desktop) browsers.

Answer (score 5):

Audio tag did not work for me in some browsers so this is how I got it done:

```
function playBuzzer(){
        $("body").append("<embed src='/web/sounds/Buzz.mp3' autostart='true' loop='false' width='2' height='0'></embed>");
}
```

Whenever I want to play sound (onmouseover, onclick, onload...) I call this function.

Comment: Excellent. This even works in IE in Compatibility Mode.

Answer (score 2):

try this: http://swaggplayer.no.de/demos
it using the flash to play a sound
or this one
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Comment: Flash is not supported on the iPhone or the iPad

Answer (score 0):

http://codecanyon.net/item/fancy-music-player-v20-jquery-plugin/498071?ref=1stwebdesigner

Player works like this  - first it detects if Flash Player 9 or higher is installed. If yes a hidden flash movie(swf) will be used, that communicates via javascript with the HTML user interface. If no Flash Player is installed, the new HTML5 audio engine will be used, which is supported by all iToys(iPhone, iPad etc.).