# Cross browser audio support (No Flash)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, audio-streaming

I want to have a small audio player on my website. It must have a play/pause and next and previous track buttons.

That's the easy part, but I want the player to work for I.E versions >= 6, FF, Safari and Chrome.

Are there any existing javascript/html solutions out there or perhaps you have done something similar before yourself and willing to share your solutions?

Answer (score 2):

A lot of info is already in this old question

[Cross-platform, cross-browser way to play sound using jQuery 1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769077/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-using-jquery-1-4)

http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/latest/demos.htm

Keep in mind that you won't find a complete cross-browser solution both for mobile and desktop that respond the very same way in each environment.

Choose your target first.

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed those.