# Add click noise to buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, firefox-addon

I've got 3 divs on my site and each one of them is a page to display like a photoslide. Please see functions and code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/EXfnN/29/

Now I need to add some button noise on the second page, for example there should be a click noise everytime when the ABC/National/Other link is clicked. How can I add a click noise to the buttons?

A proper Firefox addon would work, as this site is for a kiosk not for public. However I tried Firefox Noise Addon, but it is only working when a link is linking to a different page, but not when the link is on the same page like my situation.

Is there any way I can add a button noise to each button clicked on the second page? If so how can I do it? Any code/examples/tutorials would be great help.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Thanks for all your reply. I'm half way there with your help. At the moment there is an email submit function as well slide the page to the next when a button is clicked.

Is it possible for someone to mix those useful code below with my function [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/EXfnN/29/) please? A bit lost with one click function but two events (sound and submit an email) Thanks!

Here is the additional email submit js.

```
function abcSubmit() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "email.php", 
    data: "abc=abc", 
});
}

function nationalSubmit() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "email.php", 
    data: "national=national", 
});
}

function otherSubmit() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "email.php", 
    data: "other=other"
});
}
```

and email.php is like

```
if(isset($_POST['abc']))
{ 
$to      = 'abc@site.com';
$subject = 'Entrance notice';
$message = 'Hello ABC.';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}
```

Comment: Dont expect all your users to install those addons which helps to hear the sound

Comment: Hi Shyju, thanks for your fast response, a firefox addon would work as i forgot to mention this is for a kiosk screen not a public website. Any idea how to add a click sound? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-platform, cross-browser way to play sound from Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript), see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450033/playing-sound-notifications-using-javascript

Comment: By the way, I know it's not the point, but when a web page unexpectedly starts taking over my speakers I usually leave immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the new HTML5 `audio` tag to play sounds.
Here's a sample (it preloads and allows one sound at a time. Works in most browsers).

```
<input type="button" onclick="playSound()" value="Click me!" />

<script>

    var sound = document.createElement("audio");

    var src = document.createElement("source");
    src.src = "sound.wav";
    sound.appendChild(src);
    //More srcs...

    sound.load();
    sound.volume = 0;
    sound.play();

    function playSound() {

        sound.volume = 1;
        sound.currentTime = 0.01;
        setTimeout(function(){sound.play();},1);

    }

</script>
```

Also... don't play sounds if the user doesn't expect it ;)

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, thanks for your response. i just give your code a try, the sound is playing when the button is clicked, thanks, but I need to tell the button to submit an email and slide to next page like my code here http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/EXfnN/29/ How can keep the same function and make the sound work? Thanks very much:)

Comment: Also please see additional code for the onclick="abcSubmit()" function above. How can i mix your code with my existing code? Any direction/help is appreciated. thank you.

Comment: @SamIAm the `onclick` function can execute more than one function. For example: `onclick="playSound();submitEmail();slide();`

Answer (score 0):

[Playing sounds in Javascript](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/sound/play.htm).

Relevant quote:

> In Firefox, Safari, and Google Chrome the audio playback functionality
>   relies on plugins such as Apple QuickTime. With the audio plugin(s)
>   installed, you will need an OBJECT tag for the browser to activate the
>   plugin. Here is an example of an OBJECT tag:

```
<OBJECT DATA="audioURL.mid" TYPE="audio/midi" TITLE="Description" WIDTH=250 HEIGHT=20>   
<PARAM NAME=autostart VALUE=true>       
<PARAM NAME=hidden VALUE=false> </OBJECT>
```

You can also play sounds using Flash with plugins like the [SoundManager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager/) project.

Comment: Please provide the relevant content instead of just-a-link. You may quote your source verbatim, as you have already given attribution. The idea of this site is to have the answer *here*, not elsewhere. I've played the link-chasing game too many times, it is not fun.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to load audio, just tie the sound into your button click.  [Cross-platform, cross-browser way to play sound using jQuery 1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769077/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-using-jquery-1-4/2779515#2779515)

```
<audio id="soundHandle" style="display: none;"></audio>
<script>
  soundHandle = document.getElementById('soundHandle');
  soundHandle.src = '/blah/blah.mp3';
  soundHandle.play();
</script>
```

Comment: hi @usr1289347 and Blender, thanks for your response, I gave your code a try, it plays the sound when page load, i'm half way there, thanks. An email is sent and the page slides to the next page when an onclick="nameSubmit()" function/button is clicked at the mo. How can i mix your code with my existing functions together pls? Ive added my submit code above. Thank you!