# How do i loop a mysql query with JQuery like a chatroom?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to keep checking a `mysql` query for rows in the database the same way a chatroom constantly queries and loads new messages. In effect, checking and loading new messages as they are entered into the database.

Also, any tips on how to add a sound effect when new queries are retrieved?
Many Thanks

Comment: "like a chat room" so if it is not a chat room - what is it ?

Comment: [Here's the link to meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23326).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a repeating, timed poll. You can do this with javascript's [`setTimeout()` method](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-settimeout-javascript/).

As far as playing a sound, I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

If whenever you want to an action to be performed when data is inserted into database, is to use Trigger.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

But this action can only be another database action, meaning you cannot have your php script be notified about it.

So in your case, its best to run a cron job every 5 minutes or whatever time interval you prefer.

Try these links:

http://www.werockyourweb.com/cron-job-mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
    // call your php through ajax -- which inturn checks your db
    $.ajax({
      url: "script.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {id : menuId},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(){
        alert('success');
                    //if there is data to be populated, play sound and populate you div/textarea

      }       
    });
 }, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
```

for the sound you can try this [Cross-platform, cross-browser way to play sound using jQuery 1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769077/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-using-jquery-1-4), i have never tried but the answer has been accepted so should work. if it doesnot work you may also try this https://github.com/admsev/jquery-play-sound