# play sound clip when php/mysql if statement is true?

Tags: php, mysql

hi i have a message alert box that appears when a user gets a new message, what i want to do is add sound to this box when it pops up, i am using a php if statement to check when a user gets a new message and i have tried adding sound by doing the following but its not working please can someone show me how to do this. thanks.

```
<?php
$check_new_chats = check_new_chats();
while ($chat = mysql_fetch_array($check_new_chats)) 
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { 
        if ($chat['to_user_id'] == $_SESSION['user_id']){ 
        echo( "<embed name='sound_file' src='/assets/music/sound_file.mp3' loop='true' hidden='true' autostart='true'/>"); ?>
```

Comment: Maybe not related, but does that code need to be encased in brackets `{}` from the `while` loop?

Comment: I guess this is not really a PHP/MySQL issue.. have you checked if the embed-tag is part of your page source?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$check_new_chats = check_new_chats();
while ($chat = mysql_fetch_array($check_new_chats)) 
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { 
    if($chat['to_user_id'] == $_SESSION['user_id']){ 
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">play_sound();</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

Here's the Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function play_sound() {
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', '/assets/music/sound_file.mp3');
        audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
        audioElement.load();
        audioElement.play();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for thins, i tried this but still no audio file is being played.

Comment: @JamesPale I tried this, definitely working. Check that your path is correct.

Comment: nothing happens, just no sound plays, there's no errors nothing.

Comment: @JamesPale check the path. I'm using exact code, it's working!

Answer (score 1):

According to the question:

> hi **i have** a message alert box that appears when a user gets a new
>   message, what i want to do is add sound to this box when it pops up

You already have some sort of javascript function that displays an alert box when needed. Use the info from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769077/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-using-jquery-1-4/2779515#2779515) to play a sound with it.

```
<audio id="soundHandle" style="display: none;"></audio>
<script>
  soundHandle = document.getElementById('soundHandle');
  soundHandle.src = '/assets/music/sound_file.mp3';
</script>



//With your message alert function....
alert("Message box");
soundHandle.play();
```