# Lightweight cross browser solution for playing sound on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-platform, cross-browser way to play sound from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript)

I am looking for a solution to play sound on click (small clips) using jQuery or similar.  I would like to support ie7+ as well as mobile browsers.

Can someone lend some insight on lightweight way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450033/playing-sound-notifications-using-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript

Comment: @k4t4 beat you by 3 seconds :D

Comment: he was saying that the link you posted is a duplicate of the second link he posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of these.

1. Mike Alsup's [jQuery Media plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/media/audio.html)
2. [jmedia](http://www.contentwithstructure.com/extras/jmedia#usage) by Christoph Liell

I am unsure about IE7 support though.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Always good stuff from Malsup.