# How to play a sound with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Playing sound notifications using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450033/playing-sound-notifications-using-javascript)

I'm making a game in JS, and I need a proper way to play a sound when something happens. How do you do that with JS/HTML5? I saw [this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/sound/a/play_sound_oncl.htm) article, but even with their [example](http://webdesign.about.com/od/examples/l/bl_play_sound_onclick.htm), it doesn't really work! Sometimes I do hear that bird, but only for a short time, and I can't get it to work anymore then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the HTML5 `<audio>` tag: http://jsfiddle.net/STTnr/.

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

setTimeout(function() {
    audio.play();        // play it through JavaScript after 3 seconds
}, 3000);
```

HTML:

```
<audio src="something" id="audio"></audio>
```

Just hide the element itself:

```
#audio {
    display: none;
}
```

Do note that [no browser supports all formats](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/). This can be frustrating, but you can supply your audio in several formats.

Comment: Thank you very much, but may I ask why can't the sound be played multiple times?

Comment: @bane: If you mean looping, try adding a `loop` attribute like `<audio loop ...>`.

Comment: No, not that, I need the sound to be played when the player does something, but it gets played only the first time!

Comment: @bane: Oh I see. Well you can put the seeker at the beginning and play again: http://jsfiddle.net/STTnr/2/.

Comment: I did that, and it's acting funny. It doesn't work with my local sound (.wav), but when I use the wikipedia example - it does! Maybe it is something with the file format...

Comment: @bane: Perhaps you're using Google Chrome, in which `.wav` is not supported (look at the article I posted a link to).

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much, again! Although, ".wav" seems to be not unsupported, but half-supported... I'll both ".wav" and ".mp3", so it will, hopefully, work for everyone.

Answer (score 9):

HTML5 has the new `<audio>`-Tag that can be used to play sound. It even has a pretty simple JavaScript Interface:

```
<audio id="sound1" src="yoursound.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play();">Play it</button>
```