# Play sound file when image is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, playback, background-music

I am not a native `HTML` programmer, so please don't jump all over me about this simple question.

I have an image that, I am displaying using the following code:

```
 <img name="track1" src="images/track1.png" width="180" height="180" border="0" id="track1" alt="" />
```

I want a sound file to be played when that image is clicked. I can make the image a button, but that is messing up the layout of the page for some reason.

I am okay with using any player, but the only thing is that I do not want to display an intrusive player. I just want the user to press the image and hear the music. If he presses another image, the current music needs to stop playing, and a different sound must be played.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: you can use the [html5 audio tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp) and make use of javascript to start it after clicking

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489710/how-can-i-play-sound-in-jquery-when-click-a-button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).
You may create some `<div>` in your page having some id, for example;

`<div id="wrap">&nbsp;</div>`.

Then, in your JavaScript, when you want to play the file, just add

```
$('#wrap').append('<embed id="embed_player" src="audio.wav" autostart="true" hidden="true"></embed>');
```

the whole code looks something like;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#track1').click(function(){
   $('#wrap').append('<embed id="embed_player" src="audio.wav" autostart="true" hidden="true"></embed>');
});
});
</script>
<img name="track1" src="images/track1.png" width="180" height="180" border="0" id="track1" alt="" />
<div id="wrap">&nbsp;</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do like this solution, but the JavaScript tag description says "Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected." Perhaps this would be a good supplement to a pure JavaScript answer.

Answer (score 5):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620930/1459653)  by @[klaustopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767272/klaustopher) helped me. He wrote:

> HTML5 has the new -Tag that can be used to play sound. It even has a pretty simple JavaScript Interface:
>
> ```
>   <audio id="sound1" src="yoursound.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
>   <button onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play();">Play
>   it</button>
> ```

Here's how I implemented his advice so that clicking on the Font Awesome icon "fa-volume-up" (located on the Web page after "mule.") results in "donkey2.mp3" sound playing (note: mp3 doesn't play in all browsers):

```
<p>In short, you're treated like a whole person, instead of a rented mule. 
<audio id="sound1" src="assets/donkey2.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<a class="icon fa-volume-up" onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play();"></a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>    
    <body>
        <div id="container">
             <img name="track1" src="images/track1.png" width="180" height="180" border="0" id="track1" alt="" class="play" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'audio.mp3');
            audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
            //audioElement.load()

            $.get();

            audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
                audioElement.play();
            }, true);

            $('.play').click(function() {
                audioElement.play();
            });

            $('.pause').click(function() {
                audioElement.pause();
            });
        });
    </script>
```