# play a sound on image click in html

Tags: html

I am working on an alphabets kid learning website,  and want to play a sound on clicking an image. e.g. if user clicks on A(image) then in background sound of pronunciation of A must be played. Can it possible without using java script? Could anyone help?

Comment: without Javascript? How?

Comment: because at this time I just need prototypes of website.

Comment: I don't know if that would be possible. The code is pretty simple though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083788/play-sound-file-when-image-is-clicked

Answer (score 3):

Without JavaScript? I don't think so but the JavaScript is very easy.

You can play an audio element that you have put in your page with`document.getElementById('audioTag').play();`
So this should work:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('yourAudioTag').play();">
     <img src="yourSrc.jpg">
</a>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zefoo314/ujb19mcx/2/).

You might even be able to put the onclick method into your image tag itself like so:

```
<img src="yourSrc.jpg" onclick="document.getElementById('yourAudioTag').play();">
```

You can then use the `.pause()` method to pause the audio and `.load()` if you would like to load some new audio. It works similar to the HTML5 video tag.

And if you don't want to use an element for the audio you can declare it like this:

```
var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3'); audio.play();
```

and use it the same way. Just instead of

```
document.getElementById('yourAudioTag').play();
```

you would use

```
audio.play();
```

An example of the whole thing would look something like this:

```
 <a onclick="myAudioFunction('A');">
     <img src="A.jpg">
 </a>
 <a onclick="myAudioFunction('B');">
     <img src="B.jpg">
 </a>
 <script>
     var aAudio = new Audio('a.mp3');
     var bAudio = new Audio('b.mp3');
     function myAudioFunction(letter) {
         if(letter == 'a') {
             aAudio.play();
         } else if(letter == 'b') {
             bAudio.play();
         }
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015. it is not working on this.

Comment: this is working for me .. you may make the function more generic by initializing the path inside it       function myAudioFunction(word) {
             var base = "C/";
             var path=base.concat(word, ".mp3");
             var textAudio = new Audio(path);
             textAudio.play();
            
     }

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

Obviously, you should **go for a JavaScript solution** (like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826147/javascript-audio-play-on-click)).
To quote [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/):

> Again unfortunately, we can't tell an `<audio>` element what to do through CSS, so we'll need JavaScript.

However you have set up quite a nice challenge.

The `<audio>` element has the ability to show controls. In most browsers, the play button would come first from left in the controls.
Thus, if you wrap the appropriate `<audio>` element inside your letter element (`<div>`/`<img>`/ etc.), then, with a little absolute-positioning magic, and low `opacity` for the `<audio>`, you could put your letter "over the sound". So, when users click on the letter, they actually click on the play button.

If you use the browser's default controls, then you're browser dependent, as the controls dimensions do differ between browsers. However, you can [create custom controls](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-customized-html5-audio-player--webdesign-7081), or use players available in the market (like [JPlayer](http://jplayer.org/)), to have constant dimensions to fit to your letters.

**Example and Demo:**

The following code will make a click on the letter H play a sound of a horse, as long as you test it in a Chrome browser.

CSS:

```
div#lH {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align:center;
}
audio#aH {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.01;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="lH">
  <audio controls id="aH">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
H
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zvp382d8/).