# Immediate play sound on button click in HTML page

Tags: buttonclick, playsound

In my HTML page I have 9 images for dialing numbers and one text box that shows the pressed numbers. I want each of those images to immediately play beep sound when users click on them. I tried to use embed with hidden property and navigate it's source to .wav sound.

It is working OK, but when I press the images one after another immediately, it cannot play sound and just bees once at the end.

Is there any faster way of playing a .wav sound on 'onclick' method?

Comment: And your device and browser is....?

Comment: All of my users use Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you only need to support recent browsers, then HTML 5 offers you the `Audio` object

to load/buffer your sound:

```
var snd = new Audio("file.wav");
```

to play the sound:

```
snd.play();
```

to re-cue it to the beginning (so that you can play it again):

```
snd.currentTime=0;
```

Comment: Paul, I tried it and it works great in Mozilla and Opera. But unfortunately it's not working in IE 8 :(. Is there any replacement for "Audio" object so can be supported by older IE browsers?

Comment: HI Paul, I have tested "Audio" object in IE 9, it is not showing any Error, but not working and doing nothing? Do I have to enable any features for that?

Comment: How are the sounds encoded? IE9 only likes MP3. This chart (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) shows which browsers support which formats. If you want to cover all browsers, you will need to encode the sounds in two formats: mp3 & wav

Comment: Just a note for the context: you can load the sound file ('file.wav') here using the `<link/>` tag.

Answer (score 15):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620930/1459653 by @klaustopher (https://stackoverflow.com/users/767272/klaustopher) helped me. He wrote:

> HTML5 has the new `<audio>`-Tag that can be used to play sound. It
>   even has a pretty simple JavaScript Interface:
>
> `<audio id="sound1" src="yoursound.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
>   <button onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play();">Play
>   it</button>`

Here's how I implemented his advice so that clicking on the [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icon "fa-volume-up" (located on the Web page after "mule.") results in "donkey2.mp3" sound playing (note: mp3 doesn't play in all browsers).

```
<p>In short, you're treated like a whole person, instead of a rented mule. <audio id="sound1" src="assets/donkey2.mp3" preload="auto"></audio><a class="icon fa-volume-up" onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play();"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *embed* element for play sounds, but you've to check the formats supported by the different browsers.

[*Embed* element on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed)

```
<a onclick="playSound('1.mp3')">
   <img src="1.gif">
</a>
<div id="sound"></div>

<script>
   var playSound = function (soundFile) {
      $("#sound").html("<embed src=\"" + soundFile + "\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" />");
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I've already tried `Embed`, but it works too slow. Because users can press several buttons immediately.

Answer (score 1):

This code lets you put in a picture button; when click you get a sound. It works with Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge but I can't get it to work in Internet Explorer. I'm using html 5 codes; please copy and paste and add you own samples.

```
</head>
<body>
<script>
var audio = new Audio("/Sample.wav ");
audio.oncanplaythrough = function ( ) { }
audio.onended = function ( ) { }
</script> <input type="image" src="file://C:/Sample.jpg" onclick="audio.play ( )">
</body>
</html>
```

more on codes look at 
http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/

Comment: You can use both lines to make the sound to work for Internet Explorer but I keep getting a pop up saying;(Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls) that makes me click on "Allow blocked content"  so it will work  I'm using Windows10                                                                                                   var audio = new Audio("/Sample.wav ");
var audio = new Audio("/Sample.mp3 ");

Answer (score 1):

Example based on accepted answer (Tested in Chrome 70), but I didn't need to re-cue:

```
<button onclick="snd.play()"> Click Me </button>

<script>
    var snd = new Audio("/Content/mysound.wav"); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do to play sound effects:

```
    <html>
            <body>
        <audio id="sfx"><source src="mysound.mp3"></audio>
            <button onclick="playsound()" id="button">Play a sound!</button>
            <script> function playsound() {
    
    var sfx = document.getElementById("sfx");
    sfx.autoplay = 'true';
sfx.load();}
```

Or you can run this snippet:

```js
function playsound() {
  var mysound = document.getElementById("mysound");
  mysound.autoplay = 'true';
  mysound.load();
}
```

```css
button {
  color: blue;
  border-radius: 24px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

body {
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <audio id='mysound'><source src="click.mp3"><!-- "click.mp3" isn't a sound effect uploaded to the snippet, because I don't think you can upload sfx to snippets. (I'm new to stackoverflow, so there might be a way) But if you actually use a sound effect in that folder that you're using, it works.  --></audio>
  <button id='btn' onclick='playsound()'>Play a sound!</button>
</body>

</html>
```