# Play a sound each time a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I've struggled some time to find a working way of playing a sound when a linked is clicked on, and finally came up with the following:

```
<audio id="sound0" src="/sounds/foo">

<a href="javascript:play('sound0');">Click here</a> 

<script>function play(sound_id) {
    document.getElementById(sound_id).play();
}</script>
```

Now, this works fine, but only the first time the link is clicked on; after that, clicking again on it doesn't have any effect.

How can I fix this?

Comment: No `<a href="javascript:">` links, please. Use a button or something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953928/immediate-play-sound-on-button-click-in-html-page
try to see this they want this too

Answer (score 1):

Think you just need to rewind the sound.  Try...

```
 document.getElementById(sound_id).currentTime=0; 
 document.getElementById(sound_id).play();
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this up thanks to the link @MickyScion posted in the comment. The fix is to not use the `<audio>` tag:

```
<a href="javascript:play('/sounds/foo');">Click here</a> 

<script>function play(path) {
    var sound = new Audio(path);
    sound.play();
}</script>
```

Rewinding the source seems to be necessary.