# Sound in the browser seamlessly with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio

I know, I know, this is a duplicate question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450033/playing-sound-notifications-using-javascript). However, these questions are somewhat outdated, and I haven't found a suitable solution.

I would like an easy, cross-browser and cross-platform solution for playing sound in the browser using JavaScript. I use and love jQuery, and had a look at [this pluggin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/sound_plugin). I've tested the demo but was disappointed. For example, I had to allow the application to play the file. I want it to *just work* without any plugin, authorisation, etc.

I know that the AngryBirds chrome extension plays sound in the browser seamlessly but I don't know how they do it. Any suggestions for seamless sound in the browser?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by seamlessly. Chrome has html5 support. Are you trying to figure out how to embed and control audio in html5 enabled browsers?

Comment: No. I want my code to work in most browsers, not just html5 enabled browsers. By seamlessly, I mean "it just works", in the same way jQuery "just works".

Comment: Then you're pretty much out of luck in terms of native support. Mp3 is supported best, and you can use flash players in hidden containers. If you even consider wav, you're going to be very frustrated, like I was a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use [Sound Manager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/soundmanager2/) for this. It depends on Flash. It looks like it hasn't been updated in a while though, so it might not be a good choice if it doesn't already work in all the browsers you care about. [Support for the audio tag](http://caniuse.com/#search=audio) is getting pretty good.