# How to create Facebook chat like sound?

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make Javascript beep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep)

I'm using PHP for my new project. My client needs a beep sound when someone enters data in a mysql table.

Is it possible to create a sound/beep in PHP or Javascript?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450033/playing-sound-notifications-using-javascript

Comment: See a previous question D:). I think its help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this...

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="PlaySound('success.wav')">Move mouse here</A>
  Move mouse here.
 <img src="play.gif" onClick="PlaySound('success.wav')">

   <form>
   <input type="button" value="Play Sound" onClick="PlaySound('success.wav')">
     </form>
```

Or

```
<bgsound id="sound">
   <script>
    function PlaySound(url) {
     document.all.sound.src = url;
  }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

See My Answer here: [How to play sound when new record added to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702397/how-to-play-sound-when-new-record-added-to-database/9702522#9702522)

Sound Manager 2

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/