# jQuery, wav file, autostart false, how to trigger it again?

Tags: jquery, wav, autostart

I have something like this:

```
<embed id="wavfile" src='wavfile.wav' hidden="true" autostart="false" loop="false" height="0" width="0">
```

I don't want it to start immediately, I want it to start on some button click, so on button click I tried changing autostart parameter to true but nothing happens, still not starting.

```
$('#wavfile').attr("autostart","true");
```

Any ideas how to trigger it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you heard of the `<audio>` tag?

Comment: Ok, let's say I use <audio> tag, like this
<audio id="wavfile" preload="auto" src='wavfile.wav' hidden="true">
There is autoplay parameter which I want not to be active and then on click I tried adding it again through jQuery but still, nothing...

Comment: Thanks for tip, I found answer, while using <audio> tag there is function wavfile.play() which plays sound.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Comes from - among others, it's a pretty standard and well-known project - here: [Playing sound notifications using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450033/playing-sound-notifications-using-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I did saw that question/answers but it takes time to load and messes up synchronization and soundmanager2 is too complex for I think, simple problem