# How can we add beep sound for message notification in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, notifications, beep

Added sample to show message notification.Whenever we show it we have to add beep sound. Almost it imitates the behavior like desktop alert.

Can anyone have solution ?

Comment: See newer answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450033/playing-sound-notifications-using-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should help

```
<script>
    function PlaySound(soundObj) {
        var sound = document.getElementById(soundObj);
        sound.Play();
    }
</script>

<embed src="success.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="sound1" enablejavascript="true">
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response.How could be "soundObj" ? Is it a voice file OR it will use client system files?

Comment: You have add sound file and use that sound as a beep.

Comment: What voice file extensions it support?