# Audio vs AudioContext

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

If I would need to use and audio API in HTML5 right now, which one should I use? I see two APIs available: Audio API and Web Audio API.

Based on [this documentation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Introducing_the_Audio_API_Extension), the Audio API seems to be deprecated, is that correct? Is it deprecated only in Firefox and Chrome?

What happens with Internet Explorer?

More info about Web Audio API:

http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API

Comment: [Does this question help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394704/future-of-javascript-audio)

Comment: Weird isn't it? One method is deprecated and the other is not supported in IE.

Answer (score 2):

For playing audio from computed samples I think 
[AudioContext.createBuffer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createBuffer) 
 is great.
No support in IE 11 but in Edge and the others.