# to show a sound notification in admin dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

I want to show a sound notification in admin dashboard without page load whenever user place a new order from front end. please help me regarding this I have spend many hours on internet but didn't find any solution yet. Or any suggestions how can it possible notifications process in PHP ?

Comment: you may have a listener code on your admin page that will fire an AJAX request to Server After every n seconds ( 1 < n < 4 ) to see whether any new entry has arrived into the table or not.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to use Pusher. You can sign up for a free account with them (pusher.com). They provide some very simple code to get your started.

**Step 1 - trigger this code when a new order is placed:**

```
<?php
  require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

  $options = array(
    'cluster' => 'eu',
    'encrypted' => true
  );
  $pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(
    'xxxx',
    'xxxx',
    'xxxx',
    $options
  );

  $data['message'] = 'hello world';
  $pusher->trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', $data);
?>
```

Obviously you can change the contents of the array to "push" whatever data you like.

**Step 2 - code to receive the push in your admin dashboard**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>
  <script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.1/pusher.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher('xxxx', {
      cluster: 'eu',
      encrypted: true
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
    channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
      alert(data.message);
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

So, when you send a push then it will be alerted by this code.

You could then change the alert to actually play a sound. There are plenty of posts on here about how you can achieve this, for example [Playing sound notifications using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/450033/5592752)